# OpenGL extensions available on different Android devices

Tags: java, android, opengl-es

I'm in the process of writing an OpenGL ES powered framework for my next Android game(s). Currently I'm supporting three different techniques of drawing sprites:

- the basic way: using **vertex arrays** (slow)
- using **vertex-buffer-objects** (VBOs) (faster)
- using the **draw_texture** extension (fastest, but only for basic sprites, i.e. no transforming)

Vertex arrays are supported in OpenGL ES 1.0 and thus in every Android-device. I'm guessing most (if not all) of the current devices also support VBOs and draw_texture.

Instead of guessing, I'd like to know the extensions supported by different devices. If majority of devices support VBOs, I could simplify my code and focus only on VBOs + draw_texture.

It'd be helpful to know what different devices support, so if you have an Android-device, do report the extensions list please. :)

```
String extensions = gl.glGetString(GL10.GL_EXTENSIONS);
```

I've got a **HTC Hero**, so I can share those extensions next.

Comment: Do the GL Extensions vary by firmware as well as hardware?  Should people put their firmware version too?

Comment: Should this be a community wiki?

Comment: Dave: In theory firmware updates could add more support to the driver, but I doubt any manufacturer would do that instead of just bug fixes and what not. Perhaps it would be good to mention, though.

Comment: I've made and published a small free utility on the Android Market named "glInfo".

It lists the OpenGL extensions and limits, and allows to copy or mail them, this way you can ask around for device OpenGL specs, even to non-developers.

Comment: [OpenGL ES 2.x page](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3881197/opengl-es-2-0-extensions-on-android-devices)

Answer (score 7):

OpenGL ES extensions on HTC G1 (Android 1.6):

- GL_ARB_texture_env_combine
- GL_ARB_texture_env_crossbar
- GL_ARB_texture_env_dot3
- GL_ARB_texture_mirrored_repeat
- GL_ARB_vertex_buffer_object
- GL_ATI_extended_texture_coordinate_data_formats
- GL_ATI_imageon_misc
- GL_ATI_texture_compression_atitc
- GL_EXT_blend_equation_separate
- GL_EXT_blend_func_separate
- GL_EXT_blend_minmax
- GL_EXT_blend_subtract
- GL_EXT_stencil_wrap
- GL_OES_byte_coordinates
- GL_OES_compressed_paletted_texture
- GL_OES_draw_texture
- GL_OES_fixed_point
- GL_OES_matrix_palette
- GL_OES_point_size_array
- GL_OES_point_sprite
- GL_OES_read_format
- GL_OES_single_precision
- GL_OES_vertex_buffer_object
- GL_QUALCOMM_vertex_buffer_object
- GL_QUALCOMM_direct_texture

OpenGL ES version on HTC G1 (Android 1.6):

- OpenGL ES 1.0-CM

I'm including the version as retrieved by:
`gl.glGetString(GL10.GL_VERSION)`

It's pretty interesting in that it doesn't follow the specification. The profile is supposed to be before the number. It is also needed to determine capabilities. For example, the Droid doesn't report VBO support in its extension list. It does report an OpenGL ES version of 1.1, however. That means it does support VBOs, because VBOs were made mandatory in the 1.1 version.

Comment: Thanks, and good point about OpenGL ES 1.1 / Droid!

Comment: I am a bit confused. If I write code which only uses VBOs, will it work on a Droid?

Comment: Yes it will work. VBOs are an official part of the version Droid supports. They aren't listed in its extensions because of that.

Answer (score 6):

Here's a **HTC Evo 4G** running Android 2.1-update1 (Thanks Google IO):

GL_VERSION:

- OpenGL ES-CM 1.1

GL_EXTENSIONS:

- GL_AMD_compressed_3DC_texture
- GL_AMD_compressed_ATC_texture
- GL_ARB_texture_env_combine
- GL_ARB_texture_env_dot3
- GL_ARB_texture_mirrored_repeat
- GL_ARB_vertex_buffer_object
- GL_ATI_compressed_texture_atitc
- GL_ATI_texture_compression_atitc
- GL_EXT_blend_equation_separate
- GL_EXT_blend_func_separate
- GL_EXT_blend_minmax
- GL_EXT_blend_subtract
- GL_EXT_stencil_wrap
- GL_OES_EGL_image
- GL_OES_blend_equation_separate
- GL_OES_blend_func_separate
- GL_OES_blend_subtract
- GL_OES_compressed_ETC1_RGB8_texture
- GL_OES_compressed_paletted_texture
- GL_OES_draw_texture
- GL_OES_extended_matrix_palette
- GL_OES_framebuffer_object
- GL_OES_matrix_palette
- GL_OES_point_size_array
- GL_OES_point_sprite
- GL_OES_read_format
- GL_OES_stencil_wrap
- GL_OES_texture_cube_map
- GL_OES_texture_env_crossbar
- GL_OES_texture_mirrored_repeat

GL_RENDERER:

- Adreno

GL_VENDOR:

- Qualcomm

GL_ALIASED_POINT_SIZE_RANGE:

- 1, 128

GL_SMOOTH_POINT_SIZE_RANGE:

- 1, 128

I thought performance would duplicate the Nexus one. It has the same renderer/processor after all. The screen is TFT instead of OLED, but the same resolution. One of my games that takes 16-18ms per frame on the N1 takes 33-34ms on this, however. I haven't looked into why yet. The number looks suspiciously like it would if the screen only ran at 30Hz instead of 60Hz. I haven't confirmed that yet, though.

Answer (score 5):

OpenGL ES extensions on **Nexus One** (Android 2.1):

- GL_AMD_compressed_3DC_texture
- GL_AMD_compressed_ATC_texture
- GL_ARB_texture_env_combine
- GL_ARB_texture_env_dot3
- GL_ARB_texture_mirrored_repeat
- GL_ARB_vertex_buffer_object
- GL_ATI_compressed_texture_atitc
- GL_ATI_texture_compression_atitc
- GL_EXT_blend_equation_separate
- GL_EXT_blend_func_separate
- GL_EXT_blend_minmax
- GL_EXT_blend_subtract
- GL_EXT_stencil_wrap
- GL_OES_EGL_image
- GL_OES_blend_equation_separate
- GL_OES_blend_func_separate
- GL_OES_blend_subtract
- GL_OES_compressed_ETC1_RGB8_texture
- GL_OES_compressed_paletted_texture
- GL_OES_draw_texture
- GL_OES_extended_matrix_palette
- GL_OES_framebuffer_object
- GL_OES_matrix_palette
- GL_OES_point_size_array
- GL_OES_point_sprite
- GL_OES_read_format
- GL_OES_stencil_wrap
- GL_OES_texture_cube_map
- GL_OES_texture_env_crossbar
- GL_OES_texture_mirrored_repeat

Comment: Note: In OS 2.1, the functions in GL_OES_framebuffer_object were not usable from the Java API. Calling them just threw an exception. Android developer relations confirmed that they forgot to implement these. (yeah...) It's apparently been fixed in 2.2, though I haven't tested.

Answer (score 5):

**OpenGL ES info for HTC Desire (AU)**

GL_EXTENSIONS:

- GL_AMD_compressed_3DC_texture
- GL_AMD_compressed_ATC_texture
- GL_ARB_texture_env_combine
- GL_ARB_texture_env_dot3
- GL_ARB_texture_mirrored_repeat
- GL_ARB_vertex_buffer_object
- GL_ATI_compressed_texture_atitc
- GL_ATI_texture_compression_atitc
- GL_EXT_blend_equation_separate
- GL_EXT_blend_func_separate
- GL_EXT_blend_minmax
- GL_EXT_blend_subtract
- GL_EXT_stencil_wrap  GL_OES_EGL_image
- GL_OES_blend_equation_separate
- GL_OES_blend_func_separate
- GL_OES_blend_subtract
- GL_OES_compressed_ETC1_RGB8_texture
- GL_OES_compressed_paletted_texture
- GL_OES_draw_texture
- GL_OES_extended_matrix_palette
- GL_OES_framebuffer_object
- GL_OES_matrix_palette
- GL_OES_point_size_array
- GL_OES_point_sprite
- GL_OES_read_format
- GL_OES_stencil_wrap
- GL_OES_texture_cube_map
- GL_OES_texture_env_crossbar
- GL_OES_texture_mirrored_repeat

GL_VERSION:

- OpenGL ES-CM 1.1

GL_RENDERER:

- Adreno

GL_VENDOR:

- Qualcomm

Answer (score 5):

You should try going to www.glbenchmark.com. They have a nice database. And they list all extensions in their GL environment section for each device.

Comment: Wow, that IS awesome. Wish there was the same thing for the CPU, where it lists features like NEON or floating point support.

Answer (score 4):

Just got a Droid running Android 2.0.1.

GL_EXTENSIONS:

- GL_OES_byte_coordinates
- GL_OES_fixed_point
- GL_OES_single_precision
- GL_OES_matrix_get
- GL_OES_read_format
- GL_OES_compressed_paletted_texture
- GL_OES_point_sprite
- GL_OES_point_size_array
- GL_OES_matrix_palette
- GL_OES_draw_texture
- GL_OES_query_matrix
- GL_OES_texture_env_crossbar
- GL_OES_texture_mirrored_repeat
- GL_OES_texture_cube_map
- GL_OES_blend_subtract
- GL_OES_blend_func_separate
- GL_OES_blend_equation_separate
- GL_OES_stencil_wrap
- GL_OES_extended_matrix_palette
- GL_OES_framebuffer_object
- GL_OES_rgb8_rgba8
- GL_OES_depth24
- GL_OES_stencil8
- GL_OES_compressed_ETC1_RGB8_texture
- GL_OES_mapbuffer
- GL_OES_EGL_image
- GL_EXT_multi_draw_arrays
- GL_OES_required_internalformat
- GL_IMG_read_format
- GL_IMG_texture_compression_pvrtc
- GL_IMG_texture_format_BGRA8888
- GL_EXT_texture_format_BGRA8888
- GL_IMG_texture_stream
- GL_IMG_vertex_program

GL_VERSION:

- OpenGL ES-CM 1.1

GL_RENDERER:

- PowerVR SGX 530

GL_VENDOR:

- Imagination Technologies

GL_ALIASED_POINT_SIZE_RANGE:

- 1, 32

GL_SMOOTH_POINT_SIZE_RANGE:

- 1, 1

Comment: aww no VBOs for you! sorry :)

Answer (score 4):

Here is the info for Samsung GT-I5700 (Spica / Galaxy Spica) with Android 1.5:

GL_VERSION:

- 1.1 (lib version 11.02.72)

GL_RENDERER:

- FIMG

GL_VENDOR:

- Samsung Electronics

GL_EXTENSIONS:

- GL_OES_matrix_palette
- GL_OES_draw_texture
- GL_OES_framebuffer_object
- GL_OES_matrix_get
- GL_ARB_texture_non_power_of_two

Answer (score 4):

Looks like Dave Webb has a point.

Here is what I have with the original Droid using Android 2.1, which differs from what had been reported here for the Droid with Android 2.0.1.

GL Version

- OpenGL ES 2.0

GL Vendor

- Imagination Technologies

GL Renderer

- PowerVR SGX 530

GL Extensions

- GL_OES_rgb8_rgba8
- GL_OES_depth24
- GL_OES_vertex_half_float
- GL_OES_texture_float
- GL_OES_texture_half_float
- GL_OES_element_index_uint
- GL_OES_mapbuffer
- GL_OES_fragment_precision_high
- GL_OES_compressed_ETC1_RGB8_texture
- GL_OES_EGL_image
- GL_OES_required_internalformat
- GL_OES_depth_texture
- GL_OES_get_program_binary
- GL_OES_packed_depth_stencil
- GL_OES_standard_derivatives
- GL_EXT_multi_draw_arrays
- GL_EXT_texture_format_BGRA8888
- GL_EXT_discard_framebuffer
- GL_IMG_shader_binary
- GL_IMG_texture_compression_pvrtc
- GL_IMG_texture_stream2
- GL_IMG_texture_npot
- GL_IMG_texture_format_BGRA8888
- GL_IMG_read_format
- GL_IMG_program_binary
- GL_IMG_vertex_array_object

Comment: Shouldn't VBO be built in, as it reports supporting OpenGL ES 2.0? For GLES2, the extension is mandatory AFAIK, and thus not reported as an extension. The SGX 530 does support VBOs.

Comment: Yes, VBO is part of 2.0. I'm using my old Droid 1 for development, and it handles VBOs without problems. I should edit my post.

Answer (score 3):

OpenGL ES extensions on **HTC Hero** (Android 1.5):

- GL_ARB_texture_env_combine
- GL_ARB_texture_env_crossbar
- GL_ARB_texture_env_dot3
- GL_ARB_texture_mirrored_repeat
- GL_ARB_vertex_buffer_object
- GL_ATI_extended_texture_coordinate_data_formats
- GL_ATI_imageon_misc
- GL_ATI_texture_compression_atitc
- GL_EXT_blend_equation_separate
- GL_EXT_blend_func_separate
- GL_EXT_blend_minmax
- GL_EXT_blend_subtract
- GL_EXT_stencil_wrap
- GL_OES_byte_coordinates
- GL_OES_compressed_paletted_texture
- GL_OES_draw_texture
- GL_OES_fixed_point
- GL_OES_matrix_palette
- GL_OES_point_size_array
- GL_OES_point_sprite
- GL_OES_read_format
- GL_OES_single_precision
- GL_OES_vertex_buffer_object
- GL_QUALCOMM_vertex_buffer_object
- GL_QUALCOMM_direct_texture

Answer (score 3):

Archos 5 internet tablet running Android 1.6:

GL_VERSION:

- OpenGL ES-CM 1.0

GL_EXTENSIONS:

- GL_OES_byte_coordinates
- GL_OES_fixed_point
- GL_OES_single_precision
- GL_OES_read_format
- GL_OES_compressed_paletted_texture
- GL_OES_draw_texture
- GL_OES_matrix_get
- GL_OES_query_matrix
- GL_ARB_texture_compression
- GL_ARB_texture_non_power_of_two
- GL_ANDROID_direct_texture
- GL_ANDROID_user_clip_plane
- GL_ANDROID_vertex_buffer_object
- GL_ANDROID_generate_mipmap

GL_RENDERER:

- Android PixelFlinger 1.0

GL_VENDOR:

- Android

GL_ALIASED_POINT_SIZE_RANGE:

- 0, 134217727

GL_SMOOTH_POINT_SIZE_RANGE:

- 0, 2048

Guess that means there is no OpenGL hardware acceleration.

Answer (score 2):

Gl info for Samsung Galaxy Tab

```
Android Device
       samsung / GT-P1000 / GT-P1000
       2.2 / armeabi-v7a
    OpenGL Version
       OpenGL ES-CM 1.1
    OpenGL Vendor
       Imagination Technologies
    OpenGL Renderer
       PowerVR SGX 540
    OpenGL Extensions
       EXT_multi_draw_arrays
       EXT_texture_format_BGRA8888
       IMG_read_format
       IMG_texture_compression_pvrtc
       IMG_texture_format_BGRA8888
       IMG_texture_stream
       IMG_vertex_program
       OES_EGL_image
       OES_blend_equation_separate
       OES_blend_func_separate
       OES_blend_subtract
       OES_byte_coordinates
       OES_compressed_ETC1_RGB8_texture
       OES_compressed_paletted_texture
       OES_depth24
       OES_draw_texture
       OES_extended_matrix_palette
       OES_fixed_point
       OES_framebuffer_object
       OES_mapbuffer
       OES_matrix_get
       OES_matrix_palette
       OES_point_size_array
       OES_point_sprite
       OES_query_matrix
       OES_read_format
       OES_required_internalformat
       OES_rgb8_rgba8
       OES_single_precision
       OES_stencil8
       OES_stencil_wrap
       OES_texture_cube_map
       OES_texture_env_crossbar
       OES_texture_mirrored_repeat
    Limits OpenGL 1.0
       ALIASED_LINE_WIDTH_RANGE = 1,16
       ALIASED_POINT_SIZE_RANGE = 1,32
       MAX_ELEMENTS_INDICES = 0
       MAX_ELEMENTS_VERTICES = 0
       MAX_LIGHTS = 8
       MAX_MODELVIEW_STACK_DEPTH = 16
       MAX_PROJECTION_STACK_DEPTH = 2
       MAX_TEXTURE_SIZE = 2048
       MAX_TEXTURE_STACK_DEPTH = 4
       MAX_TEXTURE_UNITS = 4
       MAX_VIEWPORT_DIMS = 2048,2048
       SMOOTH_LINE_WIDTH_RANGE = 1,1
       SMOOTH_POINT_SIZE_RANGE = 1,1
       SUBPIXEL_BITS = 4
    Limits OpenGL 1.1
       MAX_CLIP_PLANES = 6
    Limits OpenGL 1.1 Ext
       MAX_COLOR_ATTACHMENTS_OES = 0
       MAX_CUBE_MAP_TEXTURE_SIZE = 2048
       MAX_PALETTE_MATRICES_OES = 32
       MAX_RENDERBUFFER_SIZE_OES = 2048
       MAX_VERTEX_UNITS_OES = 4
    Display Resolution
       Pixels = 600 x 1024
       DPIs = 168.89351 x 169.33333
    Display Configurations
       Standard
          07: R5G6B5
          06: R5G6B5 D24 S8
          08: R5G6B5 D24 S8 MSAAx4
          01: R8G8B8A8
          04: R8G8B8A8
          00: R8G8B8A8 D24 S8
          03: R8G8B8A8 D24 S8
          02: R8G8B8A8 D24 S8 MSAAx4
          05: R8G8B8A8 D24 S8 MSAAx4
    Compressed Texture Formats
       Reported
          8b90: PALETTE4_RGB8_OES
          8b91: PALETTE4_RGBA8_OES
          8b92: PALETTE4_R5_G6_B5_OES
          8b93: PALETTE4_RGBA4_OES
          8b94: PALETTE4_RGB5_A1_OES
          8b95: PALETTE8_RGB8_OES
          8b96: PALETTE8_RGBA8_OES
          8b97: PALETTE8_R5_G6_B5_OES
          8b98: PALETTE8_RGBA4_OES
          8b99: PALETTE8_RGB5_A1_OES
          8c01: ???
          8c03: ???
          8c00: ???
          8c02: ???
          8d64: ETC1_RGB8_OES
    EGL Vendor & Version
       Imagination Technologies
       1.4 build 1.5.15.3152
    EGL Extensions
       ANDROID_image_native_buffer
       IMG_context_priority
       KHR_gl_renderbuffer_image
       KHR_gl_texture_2D_image
       KHR_gl_texture_cubemap_image
       KHR_image
       KHR_image_base
       KHR_vg_parent_image
```

GL info for Samsung Nexus S

```
Android Device
   samsung  crespo  Nexus S
   2.3.4  armeabi-v7a
OpenGL Version
   OpenGL ES-CM 1.1
OpenGL Vendor
   Imagination Technologies
OpenGL Renderer
   PowerVR SGX 540
OpenGL Extensions
   EXT_multi_draw_arrays
   EXT_texture_format_BGRA8888
   IMG_read_format
   IMG_texture_compression_pvrtc
   IMG_texture_format_BGRA8888
   IMG_texture_stream
   IMG_vertex_array_object
   OES_EGL_image
   OES_blend_equation_separate
   OES_blend_func_separate
   OES_blend_subtract
   OES_byte_coordinates
   OES_compressed_ETC1_RGB8_texture
   OES_compressed_paletted_texture
   OES_depth24
   OES_draw_texture
   OES_egl_sync
   OES_extended_matrix_palette
   OES_fixed_point
   OES_framebuffer_object
   OES_mapbuffer
   OES_matrix_get
   OES_matrix_palette
   OES_point_size_array
   OES_point_sprite
   OES_query_matrix
   OES_read_format
   OES_required_internalformat
   OES_rgb8_rgba8
   OES_single_precision
   OES_stencil8
   OES_stencil_wrap
   OES_texture_cube_map
   OES_texture_env_crossbar
   OES_texture_mirrored_repeat
Limits OpenGL 1.0
   ALIASED_LINE_WIDTH_RANGE = 1,16
   ALIASED_POINT_SIZE_RANGE = 1,32
   MAX_ELEMENTS_INDICES = 0
   MAX_ELEMENTS_VERTICES = 0
   MAX_LIGHTS = 8
   MAX_MODELVIEW_STACK_DEPTH = 16
   MAX_PROJECTION_STACK_DEPTH = 2
   MAX_TEXTURE_SIZE = 2048
   MAX_TEXTURE_STACK_DEPTH = 4
   MAX_TEXTURE_UNITS = 4
   MAX_VIEWPORT_DIMS = 2048,2048
   SMOOTH_LINE_WIDTH_RANGE = 1,1
   SMOOTH_POINT_SIZE_RANGE = 1,1
   SUBPIXEL_BITS = 4
Limits OpenGL 1.1
   MAX_CLIP_PLANES = 6
Limits OpenGL 1.1 Ext
   MAX_COLOR_ATTACHMENTS_OES = 0
   MAX_CUBE_MAP_TEXTURE_SIZE = 2048
   MAX_PALETTE_MATRICES_OES = 32
   MAX_RENDERBUFFER_SIZE_OES = 2048
   MAX_VERTEX_UNITS_OES = 4
Display Resolution
   Pixels = 480 x 800
   DPIs = 234.46153 x 236.27907
Display Configurations
   Standard
      11 R5G6B5
      10 R5G6B5 D24 S8
      12 R5G6B5 D24 S8 MSAAx4
      02 R8G8B8A8
      05 R8G8B8A8
      08 R8G8B8
      01 R8G8B8A8 D24 S8
      04 R8G8B8A8 D24 S8
      07 R8G8B8 D24 S8
      03 R8G8B8A8 D24 S8 MSAAx4
      06 R8G8B8A8 D24 S8 MSAAx4
      09 R8G8B8 D24 S8 MSAAx4
   Slow
      29 R5G6B5 Native
      30 R5G6B5 D16 Native
      31 R8G8B8 Native
      32 R8G8B8 D16 Native
      33 R8G8B8A8 Native
      34 R8G8B8A8 D16 Native
      35 A8 Native
      36 A8 D16 Native
Compressed Texture Formats
   Reported
      8b90 PALETTE4_RGB8_OES
      8b91 PALETTE4_RGBA8_OES
      8b92 PALETTE4_R5_G6_B5_OES
      8b93 PALETTE4_RGBA4_OES
      8b94 PALETTE4_RGB5_A1_OES
      8b95 PALETTE8_RGB8_OES
      8b96 PALETTE8_RGBA8_OES
      8b97 PALETTE8_R5_G6_B5_OES
      8b98 PALETTE8_RGBA4_OES
      8b99 PALETTE8_RGB5_A1_OES
      8c01 
      8c03 
      8c00 
      8c02 
      8d64 ETC1_RGB8_OES
EGL Vendor & Version
   Android
   1.4 Android META-EGL
EGL Extensions
   ANDROID_image_native_buffer
   ANDROID_swap_rectangle
   KHR_image
   KHR_image_base
   KHR_image_pixmap
```

Gl info for milestone

```
Android Device
   motorola / umts_sholes / Milestone
   2.1-update1 / armeabi-v7a
OpenGL Version
   OpenGL ES-CM 1.1
OpenGL Vendor
   Imagination Technologies
OpenGL Renderer
   PowerVR SGX 530
OpenGL Extensions
   EXT_multi_draw_arrays
   EXT_texture_format_BGRA8888
   IMG_read_format
   IMG_texture_compression_pvrtc
   IMG_texture_format_BGRA8888
   IMG_texture_stream
   IMG_vertex_program
   OES_EGL_image
   OES_blend_equation_separate
   OES_blend_func_separate
   OES_blend_subtract
   OES_byte_coordinates
   OES_compressed_ETC1_RGB8_texture
   OES_compressed_paletted_texture
   OES_depth24
   OES_draw_texture
   OES_extended_matrix_palette
   OES_fixed_point
   OES_framebuffer_object
   OES_mapbuffer
   OES_matrix_get
   OES_matrix_palette
   OES_point_size_array
   OES_point_sprite
   OES_query_matrix
   OES_read_format
   OES_required_internalformat
   OES_rgb8_rgba8
   OES_single_precision
   OES_stencil8
   OES_stencil_wrap
   OES_texture_cube_map
   OES_texture_env_crossbar
   OES_texture_mirrored_repeat
Limits OpenGL 1.0
   ALIASED_LINE_WIDTH_RANGE = 1,16
   ALIASED_POINT_SIZE_RANGE = 1,32
   MAX_ELEMENTS_INDICES = 0
   MAX_ELEMENTS_VERTICES = 0
   MAX_LIGHTS = 8
   MAX_MODELVIEW_STACK_DEPTH = 16
   MAX_PROJECTION_STACK_DEPTH = 2
   MAX_TEXTURE_SIZE = 2048
   MAX_TEXTURE_STACK_DEPTH = 4
   MAX_TEXTURE_UNITS = 4
   MAX_VIEWPORT_DIMS = 2048,2048
   SMOOTH_LINE_WIDTH_RANGE = 1,1
   SMOOTH_POINT_SIZE_RANGE = 1,1
   SUBPIXEL_BITS = 4
Limits OpenGL 1.1
   MAX_CLIP_PLANES = 6
Limits OpenGL 1.1 Ext
   MAX_COLOR_ATTACHMENTS_OES = 0
   MAX_CUBE_MAP_TEXTURE_SIZE = 2048
   MAX_PALETTE_MATRICES_OES = 32
   MAX_RENDERBUFFER_SIZE_OES = 2048
   MAX_VERTEX_UNITS_OES = 4
Display Resolution
   Pixels = 480 x 854
   DPIs = 96.0 x 96.0
Display Configurations
   Standard
      07: R5G6B5
      06: R5G6B5 D24 S8
      08: R5G6B5 D24 S8 MSAAx4
      01: R8G8B8A8
      04: R8G8B8A8
      00: R8G8B8A8 D24 S8
      03: R8G8B8A8 D24 S8
      02: R8G8B8A8 D24 S8 MSAAx4
      05: R8G8B8A8 D24 S8 MSAAx4
   Slow
      22: R5G6B5 Native
      23: R5G6B5 D16 Native
      24: R8G8B8 Native
      25: R8G8B8 D16 Native
      26: R8G8B8A8 Native
      27: R8G8B8A8 D16 Native
      28: A8 Native
      29: A8 D16 Native
Compressed Texture Formats
   Reported
      8b90: PALETTE4_RGB8_OES
      8b91: PALETTE4_RGBA8_OES
      8b92: PALETTE4_R5_G6_B5_OES
      8b93: PALETTE4_RGBA4_OES
      8b94: PALETTE4_RGB5_A1_OES
      8b95: PALETTE8_RGB8_OES
      8b96: PALETTE8_RGBA8_OES
      8b97: PALETTE8_R5_G6_B5_OES
      8b98: PALETTE8_RGBA4_OES
      8b99: PALETTE8_RGB5_A1_OES
      8c01: ???
      8c03: ???
      8c00: ???
      8c02: ???
      8d64: ETC1_RGB8_OES
EGL Vendor & Version
   Android
   1.4 Android META-EGL
EGL Extensions
   ANDROID_get_render_buffer
   ANDROID_image_native_buffer
   ANDROID_swap_rectangle
   KHR_image
   KHR_image_base
   KHR_image_pixmap
```

And for htc wildfire

```
Android Device
   HTC / buzz / HTC Wildfire
   2.2.1 / armeabi
OpenGL Version
   OpenGL ES-CM 1.0
OpenGL Vendor
   Android
OpenGL Renderer
   Android PixelFlinger 1.3
OpenGL Extensions
   ANDROID_generate_mipmap
   ANDROID_user_clip_plane
   ANDROID_vertex_buffer_object
   ARB_texture_compression
   ARB_texture_non_power_of_two
   OES_EGL_image
   OES_byte_coordinates
   OES_compressed_ETC1_RGB8_texture
   OES_compressed_paletted_texture
   OES_draw_texture
   OES_fixed_point
   OES_matrix_get
   OES_query_matrix
   OES_read_format
   OES_single_precision
Limits OpenGL 1.0
   ALIASED_LINE_WIDTH_RANGE = 0,134217727
   ALIASED_POINT_SIZE_RANGE = 0,134217727
   MAX_ELEMENTS_INDICES = 0
   MAX_ELEMENTS_VERTICES = 0
   MAX_LIGHTS = 8
   MAX_MODELVIEW_STACK_DEPTH = 16
   MAX_PROJECTION_STACK_DEPTH = 2
   MAX_TEXTURE_SIZE = 4096
   MAX_TEXTURE_STACK_DEPTH = 2
   MAX_TEXTURE_UNITS = 2
   MAX_VIEWPORT_DIMS = 4096,4096
   SMOOTH_LINE_WIDTH_RANGE = 0,2048
   SMOOTH_POINT_SIZE_RANGE = 0,2048
   SUBPIXEL_BITS = 4
Limits OpenGL 1.1
   MAX_CLIP_PLANES = 6
Limits OpenGL 1.1 Ext
   MAX_COLOR_ATTACHMENTS_OES = 0
   MAX_CUBE_MAP_TEXTURE_SIZE = 0
   MAX_PALETTE_MATRICES_OES = 0
   MAX_RENDERBUFFER_SIZE_OES = 0
   MAX_VERTEX_UNITS_OES = 0
Display Resolution
   Pixels = 240 x 320
   DPIs = 124.408165 x 125.04615
Display Configurations
   Slow
      00: R5G6B5 Native
      01: R5G6B5 D16 Native
      02: R8G8B8 Native
      03: R8G8B8 D16 Native
      04: R8G8B8A8 Native
      05: R8G8B8A8 D16 Native
      06: A8 Native
      07: A8 D16 Native
Compressed Texture Formats
   Reported
      8b90: PALETTE4_RGB8_OES
      8b91: PALETTE4_RGBA8_OES
      8b92: PALETTE4_R5_G6_B5_OES
      8b93: PALETTE4_RGBA4_OES
      8b94: PALETTE4_RGB5_A1_OES
      8b95: PALETTE8_RGB8_OES
      8b96: PALETTE8_RGBA8_OES
      8b97: PALETTE8_R5_G6_B5_OES
      8b98: PALETTE8_RGBA4_OES
      8b99: PALETTE8_RGB5_A1_OES
      8d64: ETC1_RGB8_OES
EGL Vendor & Version
   Android
   1.4 Android META-EGL
EGL Extensions
   ANDROID_get_render_buffer
   ANDROID_image_native_buffer
   ANDROID_swap_rectangle
   KHR_image
   KHR_image_base
   KHR_image_pixmap
```

Answer (score 1):

Great initiative dude!
I thought it would be nice to also put the specs for the emulator. This is running Android 2.1

- GL_OES_byte_coordinates
- GL_OES_fixed_point
- GL_OES_single_precision
- GL_OES_read_format
- GL_OES_compressed_paletted_texture
- GL_OES_draw_texture
- GL_OES_matrix_get
- GL_OES_query_matrix
- GL_OES_EGL_image
- GL_ARB_texture_compression
- GL_ARB_texture_non_power_of_two
- GL_ANDROID_user_clip_plane
- GL_ANDROID_vertex_buffer_object
- GL_ANDROID_generate_mipmap

Answer (score 1):

This is output for my Sony Ericsson Xperia X10 with the 2.1 Update. I will add the specs for the same phone running 1.6 later.

- GL_AMD_compressed_3DC_texture
- GL_AMD_compressed_ATC_texture
- GL_ARB_texture_env_combine
- GL_ARB_texture_env_dot3
- GL_ARB_texture_mirrored_repeat
- GL_ARB_vertex_buffer_object
- GL_ATI_compressed_texture_atitc
- GL_ATI_texture_compression_atitc
- GL_EXT_blend_equation_separate
- GL_EXT_blend_func_separate
- GL_EXT_blend_minmax
- GL_EXT_blend_subtract
- GL_EXT_stencil_wrap
- GL_OES_E - GL_image
- GL_OES_blend_equation_separate
- GL_OES_blend_func_separate
- GL_OES_blend_subtract
- GL_OES_compressed_ETC1_RGB8_texture
- GL_OES_compressed_paletted_texture
- GL_OES_draw_texture
- GL_OES_extended_matrix_palette
- GL_OES_framebuffer_object
- GL_OES_matrix_palette
- GL_OES_point_size_array
- GL_OES_point_sprite
- GL_OES_read_format
- GL_OES_stencil_wrap
- GL_OES_texture_cube_map
- GL_OES_texture_env_crossbar
- GL_OES_texture_mirrored_repeat

Answer (score 1):

Tis is output from Sony Erocsson Xperia X10 with Android 1.6 (without the 2.1 update):

- GL_AMD_compressed_3DC_texture
- GL_AMD_compressed_ATC_texture
- GL_ARB_texture_env_combine
- GL_ARB_texture_env_dot3
- GL_ARB_texture_mirrored_repeat
- GL_ARB_vertex_buffer_object
- GL_ATI_compressed_texture_atitc
- GL_ATI_texture_compression_atitc
- GL_EXT_blend_equation_separate
- GL_EXT_blend_func_separate
- GL_EXT_blend_minmax
- GL_EXT_blend_subtract
- GL_EXT_stencil_wrap
- GL_OES_blend_equation_separate
- GL_OES_blend_func_separate
- GL_OES_blend_subtract
- GL_OES_compressed_ETC1_RGB8_texture
- GL_OES_compressed_paletted_texture
- GL_OES_draw_texture
- GL_OES_extended_matrix_palette
- GL_OES_framebuffer_object
- GL_OES_matrix_palette
- GL_OES_point_size_array
- GL_OES_point_sprite
- GL_OES_read_format
- GL_OES_stencil_wrap
- GL_OES_texture_cube_map
- GL_OES_texture_env_crossbar
- GL_OES_texture_mirrored_repeat

Answer (score 1):

Samsung Galaxy S, Android 2.1

Android Device

- samsung / GT-I9000 / GT-I9000
- 2.1-update1 / armeabi-v7a

OpenGL Version

- OpenGL ES-CM 1.1

OpenGL Vendor

- Imagination Technologies

OpenGL Renderer

- PowerVR SGX 540

OpenGL Extensions

- EXT_multi_draw_arrays
- EXT_texture_format_BGRA8888
- IMG_read_format
- IMG_texture_compression_pvrtc
- IMG_texture_format_BGRA8888
- IMG_texture_stream
- IMG_vertex_program
- OES_EGL_image
- OES_blend_equation_separate
- OES_blend_func_separate
- OES_blend_subtract
- OES_byte_coordinates
- OES_compressed_ETC1_RGB8_texture
- OES_compressed_paletted_texture
- OES_depth24
- OES_draw_texture
- OES_extended_matrix_palette
- OES_fixed_point
- OES_framebuffer_object
- OES_mapbuffer
- OES_matrix_get
- OES_matrix_palette
- OES_point_size_array
- OES_point_sprite
- OES_query_matrix
- OES_read_format
- OES_required_internalformat
- OES_rgb8_rgba8
- OES_single_precision
- OES_stencil8
- OES_stencil_wrap
- OES_texture_cube_map
- OES_texture_env_crossbar
- OES_texture_mirrored_repeat

Comment: I have this phone too - sad to see no VBO support. However, this handset has higher frame rates then any other i've compared it to.

Answer (score 1):

Android Device

- Xperia x10 / X10i
- 2.1-update1 / armeabi-v7a

OpenGL Version

- OpenGL ES-CM 1.1

OpenGL Vendor

- Qualcomm

OpenGL Renderer

- Adreno

GL Extensions

- GL_AMD_compressed_3DC_texture
- GL_AMD_compressed_ATC_texture
- GL_ARB_texture_env_combine
- GL_ARB_texture_env_dot3
- GL_ARB_texture_mirrored_repeat
- GL_ARB_vertex_buffer_object
- GL_ATI_compressed_texture_atitc
- GL_ATI_texture_compression_atitc
- GL_EXT_blend_equation_separate
- GL_EXT_blend_func_separate
- GL_EXT_blend_minmax
- GL_EXT_blend_subtract
- GL_EXT_stencil_wrap
- GL_OES_EGL_image
- GL_OES_blend_equation_separate
- GL_OES_blend_func_separate
- GL_OES_blend_subtract
- GL_OES_compressed_ETC1_RGB8_texture
- GL_OES_compressed_paletted_texture
- GL_OES_draw_texture
- GL_OES_extended_matrix_palette
- GL_OES_framebuffer_object
- GL_OES_matrix_palette
- GL_OES_point_size_array
- GL_OES_point_sprite
- GL_OES_read_format
- GL_OES_stencil_wrap
- GL_OES_texture_cube_map
- GL_OES_texture_env_crossbar
- GL_OES_texture_mirrored_repeat

GL_OES_EGL_image is new in update 2.1 (not present in 1.6)

Answer (score 1):

Here's the Motorola Cliq, running a 1.1 hack found [here](http://simply-android.com/discussion/833/mod-opengl-es-1.1-for-motorola-cliq/p1):

```
Android Device
   motorola / morr / MB200
   2.1-update1 / armeabi
OpenGL Version
   OpenGL ES 1.1-CM
OpenGL Vendor
   QUALCOMM, Inc.
OpenGL Renderer
   Q3Dimension MSM7230 01.02.08 0 4.0.0
OpenGL Extensions
   ARB_texture_env_combine
   ARB_texture_env_crossbar
   ARB_texture_env_dot3
   ARB_texture_mirrored_repeat
   ARB_vertex_buffer_object
   ATI_extended_texture_coordinate_data_formats
   ATI_imageon_misc
   ATI_texture_compression_atitc
   EXT_blend_equation_separate
   EXT_blend_func_separate
   EXT_blend_minmax
   EXT_blend_subtract
   EXT_stencil_wrap
   OES_byte_coordinates
   OES_compressed_paletted_texture
   OES_draw_texture
   OES_fixed_point
   OES_matrix_palette
   OES_point_size_array
   OES_point_sprite
   OES_read_format
   OES_single_precision
   OES_vertex_buffer_object
   QUALCOMM_direct_texture
   QUALCOMM_vertex_buffer_object
Limits OpenGL 1.0
   ALIASED_LINE_WIDTH_RANGE = 1,1
   ALIASED_POINT_SIZE_RANGE = 1,32
   MAX_ELEMENTS_INDICES = 65536
   MAX_ELEMENTS_VERTICES = 65536
   MAX_LIGHTS = 8
   MAX_MODELVIEW_STACK_DEPTH = 16
   MAX_PROJECTION_STACK_DEPTH = 2
   MAX_TEXTURE_SIZE = 1024
   MAX_TEXTURE_STACK_DEPTH = 2
   MAX_TEXTURE_UNITS = 2
   MAX_VIEWPORT_DIMS = 320,455
   SMOOTH_LINE_WIDTH_RANGE = 1,1
   SMOOTH_POINT_SIZE_RANGE = 1,32
   SUBPIXEL_BITS = 2
Limits OpenGL 1.1
   MAX_CLIP_PLANES = 0
Limits OpenGL 1.1 Ext
   MAX_COLOR_ATTACHMENTS_OES = 0
   MAX_CUBE_MAP_TEXTURE_SIZE = 0
   MAX_PALETTE_MATRICES_OES = 48
   MAX_RENDERBUFFER_SIZE_OES = 0
   MAX_VERTEX_UNITS_OES = 4
Display Resolution
   Pixels = 320 x 480
   DPIs = 159.37254 x 160.42105
Display Configurations
   Standard
      00: R5G6B5
      05: R5G5B5A1
      14: R5G6B5 S4
      06: R5G5B5A1 S4
      15: R5G6B5 D16
      07: R5G5B5A1 D16
      04: R5G6B5 D16 S4
      08: R5G5B5A1 D16 S4
   Non Conformant
      09: R4G4B4A4
      10: R4G4B4A4 S4
      11: R4G4B4A4 D16
      12: R4G4B4A4 D16 S4
      13: R8G8B8A8
      01: R8G8B8A8 S4
      02: R8G8B8A8 D16
      03: R8G8B8A8 D16 S4
   Slow
      16: R5G6B5 Native
      17: R5G6B5 D16 Native
      18: R8G8B8 Native
      19: R8G8B8 D16 Native
      20: R8G8B8A8 Native
      21: R8G8B8A8 D16 Native
      22: A8 Native
      23: A8 D16 Native
Compressed Texture Formats
   Reported
      8b90: PALETTE4_RGB8_OES
      8b91: PALETTE4_RGBA8_OES
      8b92: PALETTE4_R5_G6_B5_OES
      8b93: PALETTE4_RGBA4_OES
      8b94: PALETTE4_RGB5_A1_OES
      8b95: PALETTE8_RGB8_OES
      8b96: PALETTE8_RGBA8_OES
      8b97: PALETTE8_R5_G6_B5_OES
      8b98: PALETTE8_RGBA4_OES
      8b99: PALETTE8_RGB5_A1_OES
EGL Vendor & Version
   Android
   1.4 Android META-EGL
EGL Extensions
   ANDROID_get_render_buffer
   ANDROID_image_native_buffer
   ANDROID_swap_rectangle
   KHR_image
   KHR_image_base
   KHR_image_pixmap
```

Answer (score 1):

Here's the output of glInfo for my HTC Desire (T-mobile branded)

```
Android Device
   HTC / bravo / HTC Desire
   2.2 / armeabi-v7a
OpenGL Version
   OpenGL ES-CM 1.1
OpenGL Vendor
   Qualcomm
OpenGL Renderer
   Adreno
OpenGL Extensions
   AMD_compressed_3DC_texture
   AMD_compressed_ATC_texture
   ARB_texture_env_combine
   ARB_texture_env_dot3
   ARB_texture_mirrored_repeat
   ARB_vertex_buffer_object
   ATI_compressed_texture_atitc
   ATI_texture_compression_atitc
   EXT_blend_equation_separate
   EXT_blend_func_separate
   EXT_blend_minmax
   EXT_blend_subtract
   EXT_stencil_wrap
   OES_EGL_image
   OES_blend_equation_separate
   OES_blend_func_separate
   OES_blend_subtract
   OES_compressed_ETC1_RGB8_texture
   OES_compressed_paletted_texture
   OES_draw_texture
   OES_extended_matrix_palette
   OES_framebuffer_object
   OES_matrix_palette
   OES_point_size_array
   OES_point_sprite
   OES_read_format
   OES_stencil_wrap
   OES_texture_cube_map
   OES_texture_env_crossbar
   OES_texture_mirrored_repeat
Limits OpenGL 1.0
   ALIASED_LINE_WIDTH_RANGE = 1,8
   ALIASED_POINT_SIZE_RANGE = 1,128
   MAX_ELEMENTS_INDICES = 0
   MAX_ELEMENTS_VERTICES = 0
   MAX_LIGHTS = 8
   MAX_MODELVIEW_STACK_DEPTH = 16
   MAX_PROJECTION_STACK_DEPTH = 4
   MAX_TEXTURE_SIZE = 2048
   MAX_TEXTURE_STACK_DEPTH = 2
   MAX_TEXTURE_UNITS = 2
   MAX_VIEWPORT_DIMS = 2048,2048
   SMOOTH_LINE_WIDTH_RANGE = 1,1
   SMOOTH_POINT_SIZE_RANGE = 1,128
   SUBPIXEL_BITS = 2
Limits OpenGL 1.1
   MAX_CLIP_PLANES = 1
Limits OpenGL 1.1 Ext
   MAX_COLOR_ATTACHMENTS_OES = 0
   MAX_CUBE_MAP_TEXTURE_SIZE = 2048
   MAX_PALETTE_MATRICES_OES = 20
   MAX_RENDERBUFFER_SIZE_OES = 2048
   MAX_VERTEX_UNITS_OES = 4
Display Resolution
   Pixels = 480 x 800
   DPIs = 254.0 x 254.0
Display Configurations
   Standard
      06: R5G6B5
      07: R5G6B5 D16
      08: R5G6B5 D24 S8
      09: R8G8B8A8
      10: R8G8B8A8 D16
      11: R8G8B8A8 D24 S8
      12: R8G8B8
      13: R8G8B8 D16
      14: R8G8B8 D24 S8
      36: R5G6B5 MSAAx4
      37: R5G6B5 D16 MSAAx4
      38: R5G6B5 D24 S8 MSAAx4
      39: R8G8B8A8 MSAAx4
      40: R8G8B8A8 D16 MSAAx4
      41: R8G8B8A8 D24 S8 MSAAx4
      42: R8G8B8 MSAAx4
      43: R8G8B8 D16 MSAAx4
      44: R8G8B8 D24 S8 MSAAx4
   Non Conformant
      21: R5G6B5 MSAAx2
      22: R5G6B5 D16 MSAAx2
      23: R5G6B5 D24 S8 MSAAx2
      24: R8G8B8A8 MSAAx2
      25: R8G8B8A8 D16 MSAAx2
      26: R8G8B8A8 D24 S8 MSAAx2
      27: R8G8B8 MSAAx2
      28: R8G8B8 D16 MSAAx2
      29: R8G8B8 D24 S8 MSAAx2
   Slow
      45: R5G6B5 Native
      46: R5G6B5 D16 Native
      47: R8G8B8 Native
      48: R8G8B8 D16 Native
      49: R8G8B8A8 Native
      50: R8G8B8A8 D16 Native
      51: A8 Native
      52: A8 D16 Native
Compressed Texture Formats
   Reported
      8b90: PALETTE4_RGB8_OES
      8b91: PALETTE4_RGBA8_OES
      8b92: PALETTE4_R5_G6_B5_OES
      8b93: PALETTE4_RGBA4_OES
      8b94: PALETTE4_RGB5_A1_OES
      8b95: PALETTE8_RGB8_OES
      8b96: PALETTE8_RGBA8_OES
      8b97: PALETTE8_R5_G6_B5_OES
      8b98: PALETTE8_RGBA4_OES
      8b99: PALETTE8_RGB5_A1_OES
   Implicit
      87f9: 3DC_X_AMD
      87fa: 3DC_XY_AMD
      8c92: ATC_RGB_AMD
      8c93: ATC_RGBA_EXPLICIT_ALPHA_AMD
      87ee: ATC_RGBA_INTERPOLATED_ALPHA_AMD
      8d64: ETC1_RGB8_OES
EGL Vendor & Version
   Android
   1.4 Android META-EGL
EGL Extensions
   ANDROID_get_render_buffer
   ANDROID_image_native_buffer
   ANDROID_swap_rectangle
   KHR_image
   KHR_image_base
   KHR_image_pixmap
```

Answer (score 1):

Here is the GL info for **Samsung Galaxy SII**:

```
Android Device
   samsung / GT-I9100 / GT-I9100
   2.3.3 / armeabi-v7a
OpenGL Version
   OpenGL ES-CM 1.1
OpenGL Vendor
   ARM
OpenGL Renderer
   Mali-400 MP
OpenGL Extensions
   ARM_rgba8
   OES_EGL_image
   OES_byte_coordinates
   OES_compressed_ETC1_RGB8_texture
   OES_compressed_paletted_texture
   OES_depth24
   OES_depth_texture
   OES_draw_texture
   OES_extended_matrix_palette
   OES_fixed_point
   OES_framebuffer_object
   OES_matrix_get
   OES_matrix_palette
   OES_packed_depth_stencil
   OES_point_size_array
   OES_point_sprite
   OES_query_matrix
   OES_read_format
   OES_single_precision
   OES_stencil8
   OES_texture_npot
Limits OpenGL 1.0
   ALIASED_LINE_WIDTH_RANGE = 0,100
   ALIASED_POINT_SIZE_RANGE = 1,100
   MAX_ELEMENTS_INDICES = 0
   MAX_ELEMENTS_VERTICES = 0
   MAX_LIGHTS = 8
   MAX_MODELVIEW_STACK_DEPTH = 32
   MAX_PROJECTION_STACK_DEPTH = 32
   MAX_TEXTURE_SIZE = 4096
   MAX_TEXTURE_STACK_DEPTH = 32
   MAX_TEXTURE_UNITS = 8
   MAX_VIEWPORT_DIMS = 4096,4096
   SMOOTH_LINE_WIDTH_RANGE = 0,100
   SMOOTH_POINT_SIZE_RANGE = 1,100
   SUBPIXEL_BITS = 4
Limits OpenGL 1.1
   MAX_CLIP_PLANES = 1
Limits OpenGL 1.1 Ext
   MAX_COLOR_ATTACHMENTS_OES = 0
   MAX_CUBE_MAP_TEXTURE_SIZE = 0
   MAX_PALETTE_MATRICES_OES = 32
   MAX_RENDERBUFFER_SIZE_OES = 4096
   MAX_VERTEX_UNITS_OES = 4
Display Resolution
   Pixels = 480 x 800
   DPIs = 217.71428 x 218.49463
Display Configurations
   Standard
      01: R5G6B5 Native
      06: R5G6B5 D24 S8 Native
      09: R5G5B5A1 D24 S8 Native
      12: R4G4B4A4 D24 S8 Native
      07: R5G6B5 D24 S8 MSAAx4 Native
      10: R5G5B5A1 D24 S8 MSAAx4 Native
      13: R4G4B4A4 D24 S8 MSAAx4 Native
      02: R8G8B8A8 Native
      03: R8G8B8 Native
      15: R8G8B8A8 D24 S8 Native
      04: R8G8B8 D24 S8 Native
      05: R8G8B8A8 D24 S8 Native
      16: R8G8B8A8 D24 S8 MSAAx4 Native
   Non Conformant
      08: R5G6B5 D24 S8 MSAAx16 Native
      11: R5G5B5A1 D24 S8 MSAAx16 Native
      14: R4G4B4A4 D24 S8 MSAAx16 Native
      17: R8G8B8A8 D24 S8 MSAAx16 Native
Compressed Texture Formats
   Reported
      8b90: PALETTE4_RGB8_OES
      8b91: PALETTE4_RGBA8_OES
      8b92: PALETTE4_R5_G6_B5_OES
      8b93: PALETTE4_RGBA4_OES
      8b94: PALETTE4_RGB5_A1_OES
      8b95: PALETTE8_RGB8_OES
      8b96: PALETTE8_RGBA8_OES
      8b97: PALETTE8_R5_G6_B5_OES
      8b98: PALETTE8_RGBA4_OES
      8b99: PALETTE8_RGB5_A1_OES
      8d64: ETC1_RGB8_OES
EGL Vendor & Version
   Android
   1.4 Android META-EGL
EGL Extensions
   ANDROID_image_native_buffer
   ANDROID_swap_rectangle
   KHR_image
   KHR_image_base
   KHR_image_pixmap
```

Answer (score 1):

**HTC Sensation**

```
GL_VENDOR: Qualcomm
GL_RENDERER: Adreno (TM) 220
GL_VERSION: OpenGL ES 2.0 1566933
GL_SHADING_LANGUAGE_VERSION: OpenGL ES GLSL ES 1.00
GL_EXTENSIONS:
```

- GL_AMD_compressed_ATC_texture
- GL_AMD_performance_monitor
- GL_AMD_program_binary_Z400
- GL_EXT_texture_filter_anisotropic
- GL_EXT_texture_format_BGRA8888
- GL_EXT_texture_type_2_10_10_10_REV
- GL_NV_fence GL_OES_compressed_ETC1_RGB8_texture
- GL_OES_depth_texture
- GL_OES_depth24 GL_OES_EGL_image
- GL_OES_EGL_image_external
- GL_OES_element_index_uint
- GL_OES_fbo_render_mipmap
- GL_OES_fragment_precision_high
- GL_OES_get_program_binary
- GL_OES_packed_depth_stencil
- GL_OES_rgb8_rgba8
- GL_OES_standard_derivatives
- GL_OES_texture_3D
- GL_OES_texture_float
- GL_OES_texture_half_float
- GL_OES_texture_half_float_linear GL_OES_texture_npot
- GL_OES_vertex_half_float
- GL_OES_vertex_type_10_10_10_2
- GL_QCOM_binning_control
- GL_QCOM_driver_control
- GL_QCOM_perfmon_global_mode
- GL_QCOM_extended_get
- GL_QCOM_extended_get2
- GL_QCOM_tiled_rendering
- GL_QCOM_writeonly_rendering
- GL_QCOM_memory_monitor
- GL_AMD_compressed_3DC_texture

Answer (score 1):

Here are extensions for Sony Ericsson Xperia Pro running updated 2.34:

```
GL_AMD_compressed_3DC_texture
GL_AMD_compressed_ATC_texture
GL_AMD_performance_monitor
GL_APPLE_texture_2D_limited_npot
GL_EXT_texture_filter_anisotropic
GL_EXT_texture_format_BGRA8888
GL_EXT_texture_type_2_10_10_10_REV
GL_OES_blend_equation_separate
GL_OES_blend_func_separate
GL_OES_blend_subtract
GL_OES_compressed_ETC1_RGB8_texture
GL_OES_compressed_paletted_texture
GL_OES_depth_texture
GL_OES_draw_texture
GL_OES_framebuffer_object
GL_OES_matrix_palette
GL_OES_packed_depth_stencil
GL_OES_point_size_array
GL_OES_point_sprite
GL_OES_read_format
GL_OES_rgb8_rgba8
GL_OES_stencil_wrap
GL_OES_EGL_image
GL_OES_texture_cube_map
GL_OES_texture_env_crossbar
GL_OES_texture_float
GL_OES_texture_half_float
GL_OES_texture_half_float_linear
GL_OES_texture_npot
GL_OES_texture_mirrored_repeat
GL_QCOM_binning_control
GL_QCOM_extended_get
GL_QCOM_tiled_rendering
```

Answer (score 1):

GL Info for **Samsung Galaxy Nexus**:

```
Android Device
   samsung / maguro / Galaxy Nexus
   4.0.1 / armeabi-v7a
OpenGL Version
   OpenGL ES-CM 1.1 build 1.8@300406
OpenGL Vendor
   Imagination Technologies
OpenGL Renderer
   PowerVR SGX 540
OpenGL Extensions
   EXT_multi_draw_arrays
   EXT_texture_format_BGRA8888
   IMG_read_format
   IMG_texture_compression_pvrtc
   IMG_texture_format_BGRA8888
   IMG_vertex_array_object
   OES_EGL_image
   OES_EGL_image_external
   OES_blend_equation_separate
   OES_blend_func_separate
   OES_blend_subtract
   OES_byte_coordinates
   OES_compressed_ETC1_RGB8_texture
   OES_compressed_paletted_texture
   OES_depth24
   OES_draw_texture
   OES_egl_sync
   OES_extended_matrix_palette
   OES_fixed_point
   OES_framebuffer_object
   OES_mapbuffer
   OES_matrix_get
   OES_matrix_palette
   OES_point_size_array
   OES_point_sprite
   OES_query_matrix
   OES_read_format
   OES_required_internalformat
   OES_rgb8_rgba8
   OES_single_precision
   OES_stencil8
   OES_stencil_wrap
   OES_texture_cube_map
   OES_texture_env_crossbar
   OES_texture_mirrored_repeat
Limits OpenGL 1.0
   ALIASED_LINE_WIDTH_RANGE = 1,16
   ALIASED_POINT_SIZE_RANGE = 1,32
   MAX_ELEMENTS_INDICES = 0
   MAX_ELEMENTS_VERTICES = 0
   MAX_LIGHTS = 8
   MAX_MODELVIEW_STACK_DEPTH = 16
   MAX_PROJECTION_STACK_DEPTH = 2
   MAX_TEXTURE_SIZE = 2048
   MAX_TEXTURE_STACK_DEPTH = 4
   MAX_TEXTURE_UNITS = 4
   MAX_VIEWPORT_DIMS = 2048,2048
   SMOOTH_LINE_WIDTH_RANGE = 1,1
   SMOOTH_POINT_SIZE_RANGE = 1,1
   SUBPIXEL_BITS = 4
Limits OpenGL 1.1
   MAX_CLIP_PLANES = 6
Limits OpenGL 1.1 Ext
   MAX_COLOR_ATTACHMENTS_OES = 0
   MAX_CUBE_MAP_TEXTURE_SIZE = 2048
   MAX_PALETTE_MATRICES_OES = 32
   MAX_RENDERBUFFER_SIZE_OES = 2048
   MAX_VERTEX_UNITS_OES = 4
Display Resolution
   Pixels = 720 x 1184
   DPIs = 315.31033 x 318.7451
Display Configurations
   Standard
      08: R5G6B5
      07: R5G6B5 D24 S8
      09: R5G6B5 D24 S8 MSAAx4
      02: R8G8B8A8
      05: R8G8B8
      01: R8G8B8A8 D24 S8
      04: R8G8B8 D24 S8
      03: R8G8B8A8 D24 S8 MSAAx4
      06: R8G8B8 D24 S8 MSAAx4
   Slow
      23: R5G6B5 Native
      24: R5G6B5 D16 Native
      25: R8G8B8 Native
      26: R8G8B8 D16 Native
      27: R8G8B8A8 Native
      28: R8G8B8A8 D16 Native
      29: A8 Native
      30: A8 D16 Native
Compressed Texture Formats
   Reported
      8b90: PALETTE4_RGB8_OES
      8b91: PALETTE4_RGBA8_OES
      8b92: PALETTE4_R5_G6_B5_OES
      8b93: PALETTE4_RGBA4_OES
      8b94: PALETTE4_RGB5_A1_OES
      8b95: PALETTE8_RGB8_OES
      8b96: PALETTE8_RGBA8_OES
      8b97: PALETTE8_R5_G6_B5_OES
      8b98: PALETTE8_RGBA4_OES
      8b99: PALETTE8_RGB5_A1_OES
      8c01: ???
      8c03: ???
      8c00: ???
      8c02: ???
      8d64: ETC1_RGB8_OES
EGL Vendor & Version
   Android
   1.4 Android META-EGL
EGL Extensions
   ANDROID_image_native_buffer
   ANDROID_swap_rectangle
   KHR_fence_sync
   KHR_gl_renderbuffer_image
   KHR_gl_texture_2D_image
   KHR_gl_texture_cubemap_image
   KHR_image
   KHR_image_base
   KHR_image_pixmap
   NV_system_time
```

Answer (score 1):

**Asus Eee PAD Transformer Prime TF201**

extensions:

```
GL_NV_platform_binary
GL_OES_rgb8_rgba8
GL_OES_EGL_sync
GL_OES_fbo_render_mipmap
GL_NV_depth_nonlinear
GL_NV_draw_path
GL_NV_texture_npot_2D_mipmap
GL_OES_EGL_image
GL_OES_EGL_image_external
GL_OES_vertex_half_float
GL_OES_mapbuffer
GL_NV_draw_buffers
GL_NV_multiview_draw_buffers
GL_EXT_Cg_shader
GL_EXT_packed_float
GL_OES_texture_half_float
GL_OES_texture_float
GL_EXT_texture_array
GL_OES_compressed_ETC1_RGB8_texture
GL_EXT_texture_compression_latc
GL_NV_texture_compression_latc
GL_EXT_texture_compression_dxt1
GL_EXT_texture_compression_s3tc
GL_NV_texture_compression_s3tc
GL_EXT_texture_filter_anisotropic
GL_NV_get_tex_image
GL_NV_read_buffer
GL_NV_shader_framebuffer_fetch
GL_NV_fbo_color_attachments
GL_EXT_bgra
GL_EXT_texture_format_BGRA8888
GL_EXT_unpack_subimage
GL_NV_pack_subimage
GL_NV_texture_compression_s3tc_update
GL_NV_read_depth
GL_NV_read_stencil
GL_EXT_robustness
GL_OES_standard_derivatives
GL_NV_EGL_stream_consumer_external
GL_NV_coverage_sample
GL_EXT_occlusion_query_boolean
GL_NV_timer_query
```

Just grabbed the device from colleague's desk and quickly read the extension string, didn't have a chance to get OpenGL version (should be "OpenGL ES 2.0") and renderer (should be "NVIDIA Tegra 3").