# Android PixelFormat per device

Tags: android, camera, preview, pixelformat

analogous to this thread:
[OpenGL extensions available on different Android devices](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2093594/opengl-extensions-available-on-different-android-devices)
I would like to collect the different PixelFormats the android devices use.

To find out you must do the following:

```
Parameters camParams = camera.getParameters();
int format = camParams.getPreviewFormat();
```

Now you got to find the number in the following list:
developer.android.com/reference/android/graphics/PixelFormat.html#A_8

How to generally open the camera is described here:
http://developer.android.com/resources/samples/ApiDemos/src/com/example/android/apis/graphics/CameraPreview.html

I'll have a start:

device: T-mobile G1 / HTC Dream
android: 1.6 (cyanogen mod)
format: YCbCr_420_SP

So what formats do your android phones use?
thanks in advance :D

Answer (score 1):

According to the documentation this is the default in all devices

> public abstract void onPreviewFrame
>   (byte[] data, Camera camera)
>
> Since: API Level 1 The callback that
>   delivers the preview frames.
>   Parameters data   The contents of the
>   preview frame in the format defined by
>   ImageFormat, which can be queried with
>   getPreviewFormat(). If
>   setPreviewFormat(int) is never called,
>   the default will be the YCbCr_420_SP
>   (NV21) format.

I've tried to use setPreviewFormat to change this without much success on HTC Tattoo and HTC Desire

Answer (score 0):

device: Motorola XT720(MOTOROI)
android: 2.0.1
format: YCbCr_420_SP