# OpenGL ES 2.0 Extensions on Android Devices

Tags: android, opengl-es, android-ndk

As [this page](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2093594/opengl-extensions-available-on-different-android-devices) for OpenGL ES 1.x, I collect OpenGL ES 2.x Extensions for Android Devices on this page. The listing can be found with my benchmark tool [gpubench](http://www.ellismarkov.com/new-android-app-released-gpubench-1-0-0). This information can help many game developpers.

Thanks for your help,

Comment: gpubench doesn't seem to work in Samsung Galaxy SII..? All I get is black screen.

Comment: you can try the next release: http://www.iopixel.com/downloads/gpubench.apk

Comment: Hi Ellis, I am also facing this problem.here i developed Autocad app using opengles2.0, and run successfully in google nexus7.But, when i run in samsung Galaxy Note II, while i tried to drawn multiple lines and circle , it shows only one line or circle at a time, the previous drawed line or circle is erased.. this is my problem. please see my problem in this link and help me from this struggle . this link having my sample code also for understanding my Problem.                                       http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17187032/why-my-opengl-output-differs-for-various-devices

Comment: maybe not a question, but extremely useful and top google result for relevant search

Comment: where are the results? your link says that the domain is expired, etc.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

**Motorola Xoom**

```
Vendor:NVIDIA Corporation
Driver:OpenGL ES 2.0
Render:NVIDIA Tegra

NV_platform_binary
OES_rgb8_rgba8
OES_EGL_sync
OES_fbo_render_mipmap
NV_depth_nonlinear
NV_draw_path
NV_texture_npot_2D_mipmap
OES_EGL_image
OES_EGL_image_external
OES_vertex_half_float
NV_framebuffer_vertex_attrib_array
NV_coverage_sample
OES_mapbuffer
ARB_draw_buffers
EXT_Cg_shader
EXT_packed_float
OES_texture_half_float
OES_texture_float
EXT_texture_array
OES_compressed_ETC1_RGB8_texture
EXT_texture_compression_latc
EXT_texture_compression_dxt1
EXT_texture_compression_s3tc
EXT_texture_filter_anisotropic
NV_get_tex_image
NV_read_buffer
NV_shader_framebuffer_fetch
NV_fbo_color_attachments
EXT_bgra
EXT_texture_format_BGRA8888
EXT_unpack_subimage
```

Answer (score 5):

**Nexus One (CyanogenMod 6)**

```
SDK:Android 2.2
ID:FRF91
OS name:Linux
OS version:2.6.34.5-cyanogenmod
Vendor:Qualcomm
Driver:OpenGL ES 2.0 1044053
Render:Adreno

GL_OES_compressed_ETC1_RGB8_texture
GL_OES_depth_texture
GL_OES_depth24
GL_OES_EGL_image
GL_OES_element_index_uint
GL_OES_fbo_render_mipmap
GL_OES_fragment_precision_high
GL_OES_get_program_binary
GL_OES_packed_depth_stencil
GL_OES_rgb8_rgba8
GL_OES_standard_derivatives
GL_OES_texture_3D
GL_OES_texture_float
GL_OES_texture_half_float
GL_OES_texture_half_float_linear
GL_OES_texture_npot
GL_OES_vertex_half_float
GL_OES_vertex_type_10_10_10_2
GL_AMD_compressed_3DC_texture
GL_AMD_compressed_ATC_texture
GL_AMD_performance_monitor
GL_AMD_program_binary_Z400
GL_EXT_texture_filter_anisotropic
GL_EXT_texture_format_BGRA8888
GL_EXT_texture_type_2_10_10_10_REV
GL_NV_fence
GL_QCOM_driver_control
GL_QCOM_perfmon_global_mode
GL_QCOM_extended_get
GL_QCOM_extended_get2
GL_QCOM_tiled_rendering
GL_QCOM_writeonly_rendering
GL_QCOM_memory_monitor
```

Answer (score 5):

Toshiba Folio 100 (FolioMod 1.4)

```
SDK:Android 2.2
ID:TOSHIBA_FOLIO_AND_A
OS name:Linux
OS version:2.6.32.9

Model:SGH-T849
Product:SGH-T849
Board:SGH-T849
Brand:samsung

Name:armeabi-v7a
Max Freq:1000Mhz
Min Freq:216Mhz
Cores:1
Arch:7
BogoMips: 1998.84

Total:374 Mo
Free:5 Mo

Width:600px
Height:1024px
Density:1,00(160,00|160,00)

Vendor:NVIDIA Corporation
Driver:OpenGL ES 2.0
Render:NVIDIA Tegra

NV_platform_binary
OES_rgb8_rgba8
OES_fbo_render_mipmap
NV_depth_nonlinear
NV_draw_path
OES_EGL_image
OES_vertex_half_float
NV_framebuffer_vertex_attrib_array
NV_coverage_sample
OES_mapbuffer
ARB_draw_buffers
EXT_Cg_shader
EXT_packed_float
OES_texture_half_float
OES_texture_float
EXT_texture_array
OES_compressed_ETC1_RGB8_texture
EXT_texture_compression_latc
EXT_texture_compression_dxt1
EXT_texture_compression_s3tc
EXT_texture_filter_anisotropic
NV_get_tex_image
NV_read_buffer
NV_shader_framebuffer_fetch
NV_fbo_color_attachments
EXT_bgra
EXT_texture_format_BGRA8888
EXT_unpack_subimage
```

Answer (score 4):

**Samsung Galaxy S2**

```
GL_VENDOR:                      ARM
GL_RENDERER:                    Mali-400 MP
GL_VERSION:                     OpenGL ES 2.0
GL_SHADING_LANGUAGE_VERSION:    OpenGL ES GLSL ES 1.00
GL_EXTENSIONS:                  GL_OES_texture_npot
                                GL_OES_compressed_ETC1_RGB8_texture
                                GL_OES_standard_derivatives
                                GL_OES_EGL_image
                                GL_OES_depth24
                                GL_ARM_rgba8
                                GL_ARM_mali_shader_binary
                                GL_OES_depth_texture
                                GL_OES_packed_depth_stencil

GL_MAX_TEXTURE_SIZE:        4096
GL_MAX_TEXTURE_IMAGE_UNITS: 8
GL_MAX_VIEWPORT_DIMS:       4096x4096

GL_IMPLEMENTATION_COLOR_READ_TYPE:      0x1401
GL_IMPLEMENTATION_COLOR_READ_FORMAT:    0x1908

GL_ALIASED_POINT_SIZE_RANGE:    [0.250000 100.000000]

GL_VERTEX_SHADER:
GL_LOW_FLOAT:           range: [127 127], precision: 23
GL_MEDIUM_FLOAT:        range: [127 127], precision: 23
GL_HIGH_FLOAT:          range: [127 127], precision: 23
GL_LOW_INT:             range: [24 24], precision: 0
GL_MEDIUM_INT:          range: [24 24], precision: 0
GL_HIGH_INT:            range: [24 24], precision: 0

GL_FRAGMENT_SHADER:
GL_LOW_FLOAT:           range: [15 15], precision: 10
GL_MEDIUM_FLOAT:        range: [15 15], precision: 10
GL_HIGH_FLOAT:          range: [0 0], precision: 0
GL_LOW_INT:             range: [11 11], precision: 0
GL_MEDIUM_INT:          range: [11 11], precision: 0
GL_HIGH_INT:            range: [0 0], precision: 0
```

Answer (score 4):

**Sony Ericsson XPERIA Ray**

```
Vendor:Qualcomm
Driver:OpenGL ES 2.0 1403843
Render:Adreno 205


AMD_compressed_3DC_texture
AMD_compressed_ATC_texture
AMD_performance_monitor
AMD_program_binary_Z400
EXT_texture_filter_anisotropic
EXT_texture_format_BGRA8888
EXT_texture_type_2_10_10_10_REV
NV_fence
OES_compressed_ETC1_RGB8_texture
OES_depth_texture
OES_depth24
OES_EGL_image
OES_element_index_uint
OES_fbo_render_mipmap
OES_fragment_precision_high
OES_get_program_binary
OES_packed_depth_stencil
OES_rgb8_rgba8
OES_standard_derivatives
OES_texture_3D
OES_texture_float
OES_texture_half_float
OES_texture_half_float_linear
OES_texture_npot
OES_vertex_half_float
OES_vertex_type_10_10_10_2
QCOM_binning_control
QCOM_driver_control
QCOM_perfmon_global_mode
QCOM_extended_get
QCOM_extended_get2
QCOM_tiled_rendering
QCOM_writeonly_rendering
QCOM_memory_monitor
```

Answer (score 2):

```
Samsung Infuse 4G

Vendor: Imagination Technologies
Renderer: PowerVR SGX 540
Driver: OpenGL ES 2.0
GLSL Version: OpenGL ES GLSL ES 1.00
Read format: BGRA
Read type: UNSIGNED_BYTE

GL_OES_rgb8_rgba8
GL_OES_depth24
GL_OES_vertex_half_float
GL_OES_texture_float
GL_OES_texture_half_float
GL_OES_element_index_uint
GL_OES_mapbuffer
GL_OES_fragment_precision_high
GL_OES_compressed_ETC1_RGB8_texture
GL_OES_EGL_image
GL_OES_required_internalformat
GL_OES_depth_texture
GL_OES_get_program_binary
GL_OES_packed_depth_stencil
GL_OES_standard_derivatives
GL_OES_vertex_array_object
GL_EXT_multi_draw_arrays
GL_EXT_texture_format_BGRA8888
GL_EXT_discard_framebuffer
GL_IMG_shader_binary
GL_IMG_texture_compression_pvrtc
GL_IMG_texture_stream2
GL_IMG_texture_npot
GL_IMG_texture_format_BGRA8888
GL_IMG_read_format
GL_IMG_program_binary
```

Answer (score 2):

```
Vizio Tablet

Vendor: Marvell Technology Group Ltd
Renderer: GC860 core
Version: OpenGL ES 2.0
GLSL Version: OpenGL ES GLSL ES 1.00
Read Format: RGBA
Read type: UNSIGNED_BYTE

GL_OES_depth24
GL_OES_stencil1
GL_OES_stencil4
GL_OES_fragment_precision_high
GL_OES_compressed_ETC1_RGB8_texture
GL_OES_compressed_paletted_texture
GL_OES_vertex_half_float
GL_OES_depth_texture
GL_EXT_texture_format_BGRA8888
GL_OES_EGL_image
GL_OES_packed_depth_stencil
GL_OES_rgb8_rgba8
```

Comment: A marvell... i didn't know they sell a SoC for tablet

Answer (score 1):

**HTC Desire**

```
SDK:Android 2.2 
ID:FRF91 OS
name:Linux OS
version:2.6.32.15-g6a358a9
Vendor:Qualcomm
Driver:OpenGL ES 2.0
Render:Adreno


GL_AMD_compressed_3DC_texture
GL_AMD_compressed_ATC_texture
GL_AMD_performance_monitor
GL_AMD_program_binary_Z400
GL_EXT_texture_filter_anisotropic
GL_EXT_texture_format_BGRA8888
GL_EXT_texture_type_2_10_10_10_REV
GL_OES_compressed_ETC1_RGB8_texture
GL_OES_depth_texture
GL_OES_depth24
GL_OES_EGL_image
GL_OES_element_index_uint
GL_OES_fbo_render_mipmap
GL_OES_fragment_precision_high
GL_OES_get_program_binary
GL_OES_packed_depth_stencil
GL_OES_rgb8_rgba8
GL_OES_standard_derivatives
GL_OES_texture_3D
GL_OES_texture_float
GL_OES_texture_half_float
GL_OES_texture_half_float_linear
GL_OES_texture_npot
GL_OES_vertex_half_float
GL_OES_vertex_type_10_10_10_2
GL_NV_fence
GL_QCOM_driver_control
GL_QCOM_perfmon_global_mode
GL_QCOM_extended_get
GL_QCOM_extended_get2
GL_QCOM_tiled_rendering
GL_QCOM_writeonly_rendering
GL_QCOM_memory_monitor
```

Answer (score 1):

**Milestone**

```
SDK:Android 2.2
ID:FRG22D
OS name:Linux
OS version:2.6.29-omap1
Vendor:Imagination Technologies
Driver:OpenGL ES 2.0
Render:PowerVR SGX 530


GL_OES_rgb8_rgba8
GL_OES_depth24
GL_OES_vertex_half_float
GL_OES_texture_float
GL_OES_texture_half_float
GL_OES_element_index_uint
GL_OES_mapbuffer
GL_OES_fragment_precision_high
GL_OES_compressed_ETC1_RGB8_texture
GL_OES_EGL_image
GL_OES_required_internalformat
GL_OES_depth_texture
GL_OES_get_program_binary
GL_OES_packed_depth_stencil
GL_OES_standard_derivatives
GL_EXT_multi_draw_arrays
GL_EXT_texture_format_BGRA8888
GL_EXT_discard_framebuffer
GL_IMG_shader_binary
GL_IMG_texture_compression_pvrtc
GL_IMG_texture_stream2
GL_IMG_texture_npot
GL_IMG_texture_format_BGRA8888
GL_IMG_read_format
GL_IMG_program_binary
GL_IMG_vertex_array_object
```

Answer (score 1):

**Galaxy S**

```
SDK:Android 2.2
ID:FROYO
OS name:Linux
OS version:2.6.32.9
Vendor:Imagination Technologies
Driver:OpenGL ES 2.0
Render:PowerVR SGX 540

GL_OES_rgb8_rgba8
GL_OES_depth24
GL_OES_vertex_half_float
GL_OES_texture_float
GL_OES_texture_half_float
GL_OES_element_index_uint
GL_OES_mapbuffer
GL_OES_fragment_precision_high
GL_OES_compressed_ETC1_RGB8_texture
GL_OES_EGL_image
GL_OES_required_internalformat
GL_OES_depth_texture
GL_OES_get_program_binary
GL_OES_packed_depth_stencil
GL_OES_standard_derivatives
GL_OES_vertex_array_object
GL_EXT_multi_draw_arrays
GL_EXT_texture_format_BGRA8888
GL_EXT_discard_framebuffer
GL_IMG_shader_binary
GL_IMG_texture_compression_pvrtc
GL_IMG_texture_stream2
GL_IMG_texture_npot
GL_IMG_texture_format_BGRA8888
GL_IMG_read_format
GL_IMG_program_binary
```

Answer (score 1):

**Droid 2**

```
SDK:Android 2.2
ID:VZW
OS name:Linux
OS version:2.6.32.9-g59f0395
Model:DROID2
Product:droid2_vzw
Board:droid2
Brand:verizon
Name:armeabi-v7a
Max Freq:1000Mhz
Min Freq:300Mhz
Cores:1
Arch:7
BogoMips: 299.95
Total:477 Mo
Free:5 Mo
Width:480px
Height:854px
Density:1.50(144.00|144.00)
Vendor:Imagination Technologies
Driver:OpenGL ES 2.0
Render:PowerVR SGX 530

GL_OES_rgb8_rgba8
GL_OES_depth24
GL_OES_vertex_half_float
GL_OES_texture_float
GL_OES_texture_half_float
GL_OES_element_index_uint
GL_OES_mapbuffer
GL_OES_fragment_precision_high
GL_OES_compressed_ETC1_RGB8_texture
GL_OES_EGL_image
GL_OES_required_internalformat
GL_OES_depth_texture
GL_OES_get_program_binary
GL_OES_packed_depth_stencil
GL_OES_standard_derivatives
GL_OES_vertex_array_object
GL_EXT_multi_draw_arrays
GL_EXT_texture_format_BGRA8888
GL_EXT_discard_framebuffer
GL_IMG_shader_binary
GL_IMG_texture_compression_pvrtc
GL_IMG_texture_stream2
GL_IMG_texture_npot
GL_IMG_texture_format_BGRA8888
GL_IMG_read_format
GL_IMG_program_binary
```

Answer (score 0):

**HTC Legend**

```
SDK:Android 2.1
ID:ERE27
OS name:Linux
OS version:2.6.29-5f084974
Vendor:Qualcomm
Driver:OpenGL ES 2.0 1044053
Render:Adreno


GL_AMD_compressed_3DC_texture
GL_AMD_compressed_ATC_texture
GL_AMD_performance_monitor
GL_AMD_program_binary_Z400
GL_EXT_texture_filter_anisotropic
GL_EXT_texture_format_BGRA8888
GL_EXT_texture_type_2_10_10_10_REV
GL_OES_compressed_ETC1_RGB8_texture
GL_OES_depth_texture
GL_OES_depth24
GL_OES_EGL_image
GL_OES_element_index_uint
GL_OES_fbo_render_mipmap
GL_OES_fragment_precision_high
GL_OES_get_program_binary
GL_OES_packed_depth_stencil
GL_OES_rgb8_rgba8
GL_OES_standard_derivatives
GL_OES_texture_3D
GL_OES_texture_float
GL_OES_texture_half_float
GL_OES_texture_half_float_linear
GL_OES_texture_npot
GL_OES_vertex_half_float
GL_OES_vertex_type_10_10_10_2
GL_NV_fence
GL_QCOM_driver_control
GL_QCOM_perfmon_global_mode
GL_QCOM_extended_get
GL_QCOM_extended_get2
GL_QCOM_tiled_rendering
GL_QCOM_writeonly_rendering
GL_QCOM_memory_monitor
```

Answer (score 0):

**Spica**

```
 SDK:Android 2.1
 ID:ECLAIR
 OS name:Linux
 OS version:2.6.29
 Vendor:Samsung Electronics
 Driver:OpenGL ES 2.0 (lib version 20.02.70.b)
 Render:FIMG

GL_OES_read_format
GL_OES_compressed_paletted_texture
GL_OES_framebuffer_object
GL_OES_stencil8
GL_OES_texture_compression_S3TC
GL_OES_mapbuffer
GL_OES_texture_npot
```

Note: these GL_OES_framebuffer_object extension is not valid. It is mandatory in OGLES 2.x

Answer (score 0):

**Acer Stream**

```
SDK:Android 2.1
ID:ECLAIR
OS name:Linux
OS version:2.6.29
Vendor:Qualcomm
Driver:OpenGL ES 2.0 1044053
Render:Adreno

GL_AMD_compressed_3DC_texture
GL_AMD_compressed_ATC_texture
GL_AMD_performance_monitor
GL_AMD_program_binary_Z400
GL_EXT_texture_filter_anisotropic
GL_EXT_texture_format_BGRA8888
GL_EXT_texture_type_2_10_10_10_REV
GL_OES_compressed_ETC1_RGB8_texture
GL_OES_depth_texture
GL_OES_depth24
GL_OES_EGL_image
GL_OES_element_index_uint
GL_OES_fbo_render_mipmap
GL_OES_fragment_precision_high
GL_OES_get_program_binary
GL_OES_packed_depth_stencil
GL_OES_rgb8_rgba8
GL_OES_standard_derivatives
GL_OES_texture_3D
GL_OES_texture_float
GL_OES_texture_half_float
GL_OES_texture_half_float_linear
GL_OES_texture_npot
GL_OES_vertex_half_float
GL_OES_vertex_type_10_10_10_2
GL_NV_fence
GL_QCOM_driver_control
GL_QCOM_perfmon_global_mode
GL_QCOM_extended_get
GL_QCOM_extended_get2
GL_QCOM_tiled_rendering
GL_QCOM_writeonly_rendering
GL_QCOM_memory_monitor
```

Answer (score 0):

**HTC Desire HD**

```
SDK:Android 2.2
ID:FRF91
OS name:Linux
OS version:2.6.32.21-gf3f553d

Vendor:Qualcomm
Driver:OpenGL ES 2.0 1309647
Render:Adreno 205

GL_AMD_compressed_3DC_texture
GL_AMD_compressed_ATC_texture
GL_AMD_performance_monitor
GL_AMD_program_binary_Z400
GL_EXT_texture_filter_anisotropic
GL_EXT_texture_format_BGRA8888
GL_EXT_texture_type_2_10_10_10_REV
GL_OES_compressed_ETC1_RGB8_texture
GL_OES_depth_texture
GL_OES_depth24
GL_OES_EGL_image
GL_OES_element_index_uint
GL_OES_fbo_render_mipmap
GL_OES_fragment_precision_high
GL_OES_get_program_binary
GL_OES_packed_depth_stencil
GL_OES_rgb8_rgba8
GL_OES_standard_derivatives
GL_OES_texture_3D
GL_OES_texture_float
GL_OES_texture_half_float
GL_OES_texture_half_float_linear
GL_OES_texture_npot
GL_OES_vertex_half_float
GL_OES_vertex_type_10_10_10_2
GL_NV_fence
GL_QCOM_driver_control
GL_QCOM_perfmon_global_mode
GL_QCOM_extended_get
GL_QCOM_extended_get2
GL_QCOM_tiled_rendering
GL_QCOM_writeonly_rendering
GL_QCOM_memory_monitor
```

Answer (score 0):

**Desire Z**

```
SDK:Android 2.2
ID:FRF91
OS name:Linux
OS version:2.6.32.21-gd2764ed
Vendor:Qualcomm
Driver:OpenGL ES 2.0 1309647
Render:Adreno 205

GL_AMD_compressed_3DC_texture
GL_AMD_compressed_ATC_texture
GL_AMD_performance_monitor
GL_AMD_program_binary_Z400
GL_EXT_texture_filter_anisotropic
GL_EXT_texture_format_BGRA8888
GL_EXT_texture_type_2_10_10_10_REV
GL_OES_compressed_ETC1_RGB8_texture
GL_OES_depth_texture
GL_OES_depth24
GL_OES_EGL_image
GL_OES_element_index_uint
GL_OES_fbo_render_mipmap
GL_OES_fragment_precision_high
GL_OES_get_program_binary
GL_OES_packed_depth_stencil
GL_OES_rgb8_rgba8
GL_OES_standard_derivatives
GL_OES_texture_3D
GL_OES_texture_float
GL_OES_texture_half_float
GL_OES_texture_half_float_linear
GL_OES_texture_npot
GL_OES_vertex_half_float
GL_OES_vertex_type_10_10_10_2
GL_NV_fence
GL_QCOM_driver_control
GL_QCOM_perfmon_global_mode
GL_QCOM_extended_get
GL_QCOM_extended_get2
GL_QCOM_tiled_rendering
GL_QCOM_writeonly_rendering
GL_QCOM_memory_monitor
```

Answer (score 0):

**Galaxy Tab**

```
SDK:Android 2.2
ID:FROYO
OS name:Linux
OS version:2.6.32.9
Model:GT-P1000
Product:GT-P1000
Board:GT-P1000
Brand:samsung
Name:armeabi-v7a
Max Freq:1000Mhz
Min Freq:100Mhz
Cores:1
Arch:7
BogoMips: 796.20    
Total:443 Mo
Free:9 Mo
Width:600px
Height:1024px
Density:1,50(168,89|169,33)
Vendor:Imagination Technologies
Driver:OpenGL ES 2.0
Render:PowerVR SGX 540

GL_OES_rgb8_rgba8
GL_OES_depth24
GL_OES_vertex_half_float
GL_OES_texture_float
GL_OES_texture_half_float
GL_OES_element_index_uint
GL_OES_mapbuffer
GL_OES_fragment_precision_high
GL_OES_compressed_ETC1_RGB8_texture
GL_OES_EGL_image
GL_OES_required_internalformat
GL_OES_depth_texture
GL_OES_get_program_binary
GL_OES_packed_depth_stencil
GL_OES_standard_derivatives
GL_OES_vertex_array_object
GL_EXT_multi_draw_arrays
GL_EXT_texture_format_BGRA8888
GL_EXT_discard_framebuffer
GL_IMG_shader_binary
GL_IMG_texture_compression_pvrtc
GL_IMG_texture_stream2
GL_IMG_texture_npot
GL_IMG_texture_format_BGRA8888
GL_IMG_read_format
GL_IMG_program_binary
```

Answer (score 0):

**VegaTab (Tegra2)**

```
SDK:Android 2.2
ID:FRF91
OS name:Linux
OS version:2.6.32.9-dirty
Model:VEGAn-TAB-v1.0.0B5.1
Product:Vega
Board:Vega
Brand:nvidia
Name:armeabi-v7a
Max Freq:1000Mhz
Min Freq:216Mhz
Cores:1
Arch:7
BogoMips: 1998.84
Total:754 Mo
Free:436 Mo
Width:600px
Height:1024px
Density:1.00(160.00|160.00)
Vendor:NVIDIA Corporation
Driver:OpenGL ES 2.0
Render:NVIDIA Tegra

GL_OES_rgb8_rgba8
GL_OES_fbo_render_mipmap
GL_OES_EGL_image
GL_OES_vertex_half_float
GL_OES_mapbuffer
GL_OES_texture_half_float
GL_OES_texture_float
GL_OES_compressed_ETC1_RGB8_texture
GL_ARB_draw_buffers
GL_EXT_Cg_shader
GL_EXT_packed_float
GL_EXT_texture_array
GL_EXT_texture_compression_latc
GL_EXT_texture_compression_dxt1
GL_EXT_texture_compression_s3tc
GL_EXT_texture_filter_anisotropic
GL_EXT_bgra
GL_EXT_texture_format_BGRA8888
GL_EXT_unpack_subimage
GL_NV_get_tex_image
GL_NV_read_buffer
GL_NV_shader_framebuffer_fetch
GL_NV_fbo_color_attachments
GL_NV_platform_binary
GL_NV_depth_nonlinear
GL_NV_draw_path
GL_NV_framebuffer_vertex_attrib_array
GL_NV_coverage_sample
```

Answer (score 0):

**Nexus S**

```
SDK:Android 2.5
ID:GRH78
OS name:Linux
OS version:2.6.35.7-g7f1638a
Model:Nexus S
Product:soju
Board:herring
Brand:google
Name:armeabi-v7a
Max Freq:1000Mhz
Min Freq:100Mhz
Cores:1
Arch:7
BogoMips: 996.00
Total:346 Mo
Free:7 Mo
Width:480px
Height:800px
Density:1.50(234.46|236.28)
Vendor:Imagination Technologies
Driver:OpenGL ES 2.0
Render:PowerVR SGX 540

GL_OES_rgb8_rgba8
GL_OES_depth24
GL_OES_vertex_half_float
GL_OES_texture_float
GL_OES_texture_half_float
GL_OES_element_index_uint
GL_OES_mapbuffer
GL_OES_fragment_precision_high
GL_OES_compressed_ETC1_RGB8_texture
GL_OES_EGL_image
GL_OES_required_internalformat
GL_OES_depth_texture
GL_OES_get_program_binary
GL_OES_packed_depth_stencil
GL_OES_standard_derivatives
GL_OES_vertex_array_object
GL_OES_egl_sync
GL_EXT_multi_draw_arrays
GL_EXT_texture_format_BGRA8888
GL_EXT_discard_framebuffer
GL_EXT_shader_texture_lod
GL_IMG_shader_binary
GL_IMG_texture_compression_pvrtc
GL_IMG_texture_stream2
GL_IMG_texture_npot
GL_IMG_texture_format_BGRA8888
GL_IMG_read_format
GL_IMG_program_binary
GL_IMG_multisampled_render_to_texture
```

Answer (score 0):

**Samsung Corby**

```
SDK:Android 2.1
ID:ERE27
OS name:Linux
OS version:2.6.29-perf
Model:GT-I5500
Product:GT-I5500
Board:GT-I5500
Brand:Samsung
Name:armeabi
Max Freq:600Mhz
Min Freq:245Mhz
Cores:1
Arch:6TEJ
BogoMips: 599.65
Total:186 Mo
Free:2 Mo
Width:240px
Height:320px
Density:0,75(145,14|142,60)
Vendor:Qualcomm
Driver:OpenGL ES 2.0 1044053
Render:Adreno

GL_AMD_compressed_3DC_texture
GL_AMD_compressed_ATC_texture
GL_AMD_performance_monitor
GL_AMD_program_binary_Z400
GL_EXT_texture_filter_anisotropic
GL_EXT_texture_format_BGRA8888
GL_EXT_texture_type_2_10_10_10_REV
GL_OES_compressed_ETC1_RGB8_texture
GL_OES_depth_texture
GL_OES_depth24
GL_OES_EGL_image
GL_OES_element_index_uint
GL_OES_fbo_render_mipmap
GL_OES_fragment_precision_high
GL_OES_get_program_binary
GL_OES_packed_depth_stencil
GL_OES_rgb8_rgba8
GL_OES_standard_derivatives
GL_OES_texture_3D
GL_OES_texture_float
GL_OES_texture_half_float
GL_OES_texture_half_float_linear
GL_OES_texture_npot
GL_OES_vertex_half_float
GL_OES_vertex_type_10_10_10_2
GL_NV_fence
GL_QCOM_driver_control
GL_QCOM_perfmon_global_mode
GL_QCOM_extended_get
GL_QCOM_extended_get2
GL_QCOM_tiled_rendering
GL_QCOM_writeonly_rendering
GL_QCOM_memory_monitor
```

Answer (score 0):

LGE Tablet

```
SDK:Android unknown
ID:HONEYCOMB
OS name:Linux
OS version:2.6.36.3-00003-g402144c
Model:L-06C
Product:stardocomo
Board:startablet
Brand:LGE
Vendor:NVIDIA Corporation
Driver:OpenGL ES 2.0
Render:NVIDIA Tegra

GL_NV_platform_binary
GL_OES_rgb8_rgba8
GL_OES_EGL_sync
GL_OES_fbo_render_mipmap
GL_NV_depth_nonlinear
GL_NV_draw_path
GL_NV_texture_npot_2D_mipmap
GL_OES_EGL_image
GL_OES_EGL_image_external
GL_OES_vertex_half_float
GL_NV_framebuffer_vertex_attrib_array
GL_NV_coverage_sample
GL_OES_mapbuffer
GL_ARB_draw_buffers
GL_EXT_Cg_shader
GL_EXT_packed_float
GL_OES_texture_half_float
GL_OES_texture_float
GL_EXT_texture_array
GL_OES_compressed_ETC1_RGB8_texture
GL_EXT_texture_compression_latc
GL_EXT_texture_compression_dxt1
GL_EXT_texture_compression_s3tc
GL_EXT_texture_filter_anisotropic
GL_NV_get_tex_image
GL_NV_read_buffer
GL_NV_shader_framebuffer_fetch
GL_NV_fbo_color_attachments
GL_EXT_bgra
GL_EXT_texture_format_BGRA8888
GL_EXT_unpack_subimage
```

Answer (score 0):

**Mali 400**

```
SDK:Android unknown
ID:GINGERBREAD
OS version:2.6.35.7-I9100XWKDD-CL161513
Model:GT-I9100
Product:GT-I9100
Board:GT-I9100
Brand:samsung
Name:armeabi-v7a
Max Freq:1200Mhz
Min Freq:200Mhz
Cores:2
Arch:7
BogoMips: 1592.52
Total:833 Mo
Free:185 Mo
Width:480px
Height:800px
Density:1,50(217,71|218,49)
Vendor:ARM
Driver:OpenGL ES 2.0
Render:Mali-400 MP


GL_OES_texture_npot
GL_OES_compressed_ETC1_RGB8_texture
GL_OES_standard_derivatives
GL_OES_EGL_image
GL_OES_depth24
GL_ARM_rgba8
GL_ARM_mali_shader_binary
GL_OES_depth_texture
GL_OES_packed_depth_stencil
```