# openGL ES versions on different devices

Tags: android, opengl-es

I want to find out range of android phones that supports openGLES 1.0, 1.1, 2.0.
I believe that I can use 1.1 and that should cover more that 90% percent of phones, but to be sure would be nice to find out any statistic information. I have tried to google but nothing useful so far.

Thanks.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Android 2.2 and higher supports Open GL ES 2.0, so as of Feb 2 that is 58.4% of phones.
Android 1.6 and higher supports Open GL ES 1.1, so that is about 96% of phones.

I think you'll be good with 1.1.

Comment: Does Android 2.1+ with software support for OpenGL ES 2.0 only run on hardware that has GPUs which support OpenGL ES 2.0, or could some of the older devices with non-2.0 graphics hardware install that OS version?  I wasn't sure about that from this presentation: http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=7-62tRHLcHk

Comment: Where did you get these stats? Would be very interested in an updated version.

Answer (score 34):

Just to update this answer for **June 2014**.

You can view the statistics on the **Android Dashboard** at http://developer.android.com/about/dashboards/index.html#OpenGL

Currently,

```
OpenGL Version       Percentage
1.1 only             0.1%
2.0                  83.6%
3.0                  16.3%
```

> Note that support for one particular version of OpenGL ES also **implies support for any lower version** (for example, support for version 2.0 also implies support for 1.1).

Answer (score 4):

It is an urban legend that devices with Android 2.2 support OpenGL ES 2.0 by definition. The [Android 2.2 Compatibility Definition Document](http://source.android.com/compatibility/downloads.html#android-22) says this:

> Device implementations MUST support OpenGL ES 1.0. […] Device implementations SHOULD provide an implementation for OpenGL ES 2.0, if the hardware is capable of reasonable performance on those APIs.

(The first version to require 2.0 support is 4.0.3.)

To answer the question, the [statistics](http://developer.android.com/about/dashboards/index.html#OpenGL) others have linked to before me currently state that out of the devices that visit the Play Store:

- 99,8% supports 2.0 and 1.1
- 0,2% supports 1.1, but not 2.0

Answer (score 3):

The Wikipedia page for OpenGL ES has a list that, for each version, says which phones support it: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/OpenGL_ES#Usage .

Comment: I expected sort of a list of devices, but the information is very vague. E.g. 'Various Samsung mobile phones, including the Galaxy S and Wave'

Answer (score 3):

From [OpenGL ES at Google/Android Developers site](https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/graphics/opengl.html),

- OpenGL ES 1.0 and 1.1 - This API specification is supported by Android 1.0 and higher.
- OpenGL ES 2.0 - This API specification is supported by Android 2.2 (API level 8) and higher.
- OpenGL ES 3.0 - This API specification is supported by Android 4.3 (API level 18) and higher.
- OpenGL ES 3.1 - This API specification is supported by Android 5.0 (API level 21) and higher.

From [Android Version Fragmentation Dashboard](https://developer.android.com/about/dashboards/index.html), updated as of July 2019

- Android 4.4, API Level 19, 6.9%
- Android 5.0, API Level 21, 3.0%
- Android 5.1, API Level 22, 11.5%
- Android 6.0, API Level 23, 16.9%
- Android 7.0, API Level 24, 11.4%
- Android 7.1, API Level 25, 7.8%
- Android 8.0, API Level 26, 12.9%
- Android 8.1, API Level 27, 15.4%
- Android 9.0, API Level 28, 10.4%

The dashboard page has the following information

**OpenGL ES Version, Distribution**

- 2.0, 21.1%
- 3.0, 29.8%
- 3.1, 13.6%
- 3.2, 35.5%

You may combine this information to decide limits for supporting devices.

Comment: It's quite odd, that If you count the percentage of devices with API level >= 18, it's 3.3%, however the devices without opengl es 3.0+ support, the percentage is 21.1%.

Comment: Ha, I guess i know the answer, according to this post: https://gametorrahod.com/dealing-with-ios-android-texture-in-2019/. for some devices, it's not hardware supported.

Answer (score 1):

Currently the question is: Can I already use Open GL ES 3.0 instead of 2.0 to get some features? See [Differences OpenGL ES 2.0 and 3.0](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17543364/what-is-the-differences-between-opengl-es-2-0-and-opengl-es-3-0)

I used http://opengles.gpuinfo.org/ for collection GL versions by devices and http://hwstats.unity3d.com/mobile/index-android.html for overal percentage stats.

Answer (score -1):

We can use the software implementation of OpenGL ES 1.1 even though cheap devices do not have GPU. If device have GPU, there is no doubt that it supports OpenGL ES 2.0.

Motorola provides complete product list includes GPU information and OpenGL ES extensions.

- [MOTODEV > Products](http://developer.motorola.com/products/)

Also it is not complete but useful OpenGL ES 1.1/2.0 extensions on Android devices.

- [OpenGL extensions available on
  different Android devices](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2093594)
- [OpenGL ES 2.0 Extensions on Android
  Devices](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3881197)

Comment: "If device have GPU, there is no doubt that it supports OpenGL ES 2.0." That is incorrect.  There are many integrated GPUs in Android and other mobile devices that support only OpenGL ES 1.1, not 2.0.  You can't rely on 2.0 support just because something has a GPU.

Comment: AFAIK, MSM720x is only chipset for Android devices that has GPU and doesn't support OpenGL ES 2.0. HTC Dream, Magic and Hero are the legacy devices. [List of HTC phones](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_HTC_phones), [MSM7000](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/MSM7000)

Comment: Any idea about the number of ARMv7 devices that don't support GLES 2.0? http://developer.android.com/resources/dashboard/opengl.html indicates that there are currently 17% of devices that are GLES 1.1 only, though I suspect that a big chunk of those are cheap ARMv5 or ARMv6 devices.

Comment: I don't know the fact, but I guess all ARMv7 devices do support GLES 2.0.