# Android OpenGL ES 2.0: Do I need to check if VBOs are supported before using?

Tags: android, opengl-es, android-ndk, opengl-es-2.0

I want my code to perform well in all devices supporting Es 2.0. In my code, I am using VBOs, reading documentation reveals that it requires the implementation of extension "GL_ARB_vertex_buffer_object".

However, glGetString(GL_EXTENSIONS) does not list the above mentioned extension string for the device I am using (Samsung Tab) though it supports it.

Comment: Nope, all Android & IOS devices with ES 2.0 support VBOs. Don't check if it is supported.

Answer (score 1):

To my knowledge, the VBO extension is only meant for OpenGLES 1.1. OpenGLES 2.0 supports this by default. [This tutorial](http://www.learnopengles.com/android-lesson-seven-an-introduction-to-vertex-buffer-objects-vbos/), which I consider one of the best, makes no consideration to test the device before running the VBOs.

Answer (score 0):

In all my Android apps I use OpenGL ES 2.0 with VBO without any additional checks.
And VBOs work on Galaxy Tab.

Answer (score 0):

In OpenGLES2 you **do not** have to check for **VBO** extension.

In OpenGLES2 you **do** have to check for vertex_array_object if you want to use **VAO** as well.

Here is a [database](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3881197/opengl-es-2-0-extensions-on-android-devices) of extensions from various devices.