# Remote Test Laboratory (RTL) for Android

Tags: android

Just known Samsung support RTL for Samsung android device:

http://developer.samsung.com/remotetestlab/rtlDeviceList.action

[image: Samsung RTL]

**[Question]**

Anyone known other free RTL for other mobile device as HTC, LG, ... etc

**UPDATE2:** [08/07/2011] Thanks [denis.solonenko](https://stackoverflow.com/users/229672/denis-solonenko)

**1.LG Mobile:** http://developer.lgmobile.com/lge.mdn.sup.retrieveVirtualDevLab.dev

**2.Motorola Mobile:** http://developer.motorola.com/testing/motoready/

**3.Sony Mobile:** https://remotedevicelab.sonymobile.com/

Comment: MOTOREADY App Testing: MOTOROLA XOOM http://developer.motorola.com/testing/motoready/

Comment: I should mention that Samsung's remote test lab doesn't support changing device orientation.  So it's kinda useless if you wanna test in landscape mode.

Comment: The MotoReady testing program is not free!  If you're a single developer, you can forget about that program.

Comment: Samsung RTL doesn't work if you are using Mac. That kinda sucks! http://d.pr/i/IdEH

Comment: For me RTL is working dead slow on window. Do I need any additional things to do to make it smoother?

Comment: I just started using RTL from Samsung website. I stuck in oe problem, i am unable to unlock the screen. It's not Swiping.. :( How can i achieve this?

Comment: LG virtual developer lab has been shifted to https://www.keynotedeviceanywhere.com/lg_vdl/LG_virtual_developer_lab.html (Partner members only).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In addition to the [Samsung](http://innovator.samsungmobile.com/bbs/lab/view.do?platformId=1), [LG](http://developer.lgmobile.com/lge.mdn.sup.retrieveVirtualDevLab.dev), and [Motorola](http://developer.motorola.com/testing/motoready/) links you already posted, I just found a service by [Perfecto Mobile](http://www.perfectomobile.com/) that has a free trial.  And, since I'm making a list, here's a service by [DeviceAnywhere](http://www.deviceanywhere.com/mobile-application-testing.html) that's not free.

Of course, there are many companies that will test your apps for you, but I thought [Duarlander](http://duarlander.ning.com/) was neat because it was comunity-based.  And, if you're looking for cheap testing, [TestingAndroid](http://www.testingandroid.com/) claims to test for $19.

These are just some free/cheap options, mostly where you do your own testing.  Obviously there are many big companies out there that would love to "work with you" on testing (for a price).

Comment: LG and Motorola and few others just have set of their devices at DeviceAnywhere. I am not sure whether it's even at least discounted compared to ordering directly at DeviceAnywhere.

Comment: Motorola unfortunately stopped this feature !

Answer (score 5):

I am not able to comment, so i need to answer here...

I tested Perfecto Mobile with the free trial and i just think its slow as hell, i just wanted to test the automation feature, which is not provided in the free trial.

But the [Samsung RTL](http://developer.samsung.com/home.do) is really nice.
Why i wanted to comment is to tell you, that RTL works with OSX quite fine and as stated above there is Screen Orientation now. Testing Samsung devices works really nice this way.

The LG Link is dead.

Comment: Samsung RTL doesn't work in OSX at the moment.

Comment: i tried it on mac os and it worked for me. [see img](http://imageshack.us/f/547/bildschirmfoto20130405u.png/)

Comment: Interesting, how did you manage to do that?:) When I go to [Samsung RTL](http://developer.samsung.com/remotetestlab) webpage using OSX there are some configuration requirements listed and one of them is that only Windows and Linux are supported ([here](http://img18.imageshack.us/img18/8489/samsungrtl.png) is the screenshot).

Comment: I don't know if i did something special. I just didn't care about the check messages and downloaded the jnlp files for the devices. You need Java to open them. Everything works fine. Maybe if you struggle somewhere i will remind how to solve this issue ;)

Comment: I have the same problem as @Piotr. This is Stack Overflow. Here we share how we get things done. How do you use Samsung RTL on OSX @Jøran?

Comment: @JannieT sorry for my late answer: i just log in at http://developer.samsung.com/remotetestlab/rtlAboutRTL.action then i check the device list, choosing a device (os version, device list), then click start. after downloading the jnlp-file, i just open it with  java 7

Comment: Thank you. I think I had the wrong version of Java installed.

Answer (score 2):

If you want to use it on Mac OSX, here's what I found successful...

1. Ignore the "test" on the main RTL page, but make sure you have the latest Java installed.
2. On the RTL page, sign up for the device, model, amount of testing time, etc. A .jnlp file will be downloaded to your local machine.
3. Double-click the .jnlp file, and Java should load it and show the RTL device.

Answer (score 1):

If you are just looking for online emulator match every current Android OS version & screen size. then try www.manymo.com

Answer (score 1):

If you are looking for emulators and real devices from different vendors like motorola, htc, samsung and co. you can try http://testobject.com (Disclaimer: I'm cofounder of testobject)