# Auto-download app on multiple Android devices wirelessly for testing?

Tags: android

I have several android devices I would like to test on. Currently, when I want to test my latest build, I have to connect each device individually. It would save a lot of time if, instead, I could press "Run" and each of my devices would automatically and wirelessly update with the latest build of my app. Is this possible?

To be clear, I am not interested in remote testing as in [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6139241/remote-test-laboratory-rtl-for-android). I want to test on multiple devices that I already own.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have a couple of options.

If you have rooted devices you can use something [like this](https://market.android.com/details?id=nl.morose.wirelessadb) to connect your adb over wifi, instead of plugging them in.

What I have started to do for non-rooted devices is copying the apk file out of the project bin folder into my dropbox, then copy the link to it and turn it into a QR code, and scan it with each of the devices.

Edit: I use a firefox bookmark to make generating the QR codes a bit easier.
[image]

This is the whole link that goes in the location box:

> http://chart.apis.google.com/chart?cht=qr&chs=350x350&chl=%s

Once you have that bookmark saved in firefox all you need to do is type "qr " in your address bar and then paste the link(or anything else) you want turned into code. This along with Dropbox's custom context menu that shows up when you right click something in the public folder has an option 'Copy public link' These work together to make the process fairly painless.