# Online tablets emulators for android

Tags: android, tablet

Can you suggest me some online android tablet emulators? I have searched many and I found http://tablet-emulator.org/ but it's not working properly on my end. Can you suggest me some good online tablets site? Please help.

Answer (score 0):

Samsung support Remote test lab for Samsung device at:
http://innovator.samsungmobile.com/bbs/lab/view.do?platformId=1

you can refer this link for more option:
[Remote Test Laboratory (RTL) for Android](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6139241/remote-test-laboratory-rtl-for-android)

Comment: First link not working anymore.