# Android / OpenGL ES: Draw primitive doesn't do anything

Tags: android, opengl-es

Trying to draw a solid cylinder doesn't do what I want it to. Here's my code:

```
public static void solidCylinder(GL10 gl, float radius, float height, int slices, int steps)
{
    float zStep = height/steps;
    float alphaStep = (float)((2*Math.PI) / slices);
    float crtZ = -height/2;
    float[] vdata = new float[6 * steps * (slices+1)];
    for(int iStep = 0; iStep < steps; iStep++)
    {   
        float crtAlpha = 0;
        int iAlpha;
        for (iAlpha = 0; iAlpha <= slices; iAlpha++)
        { 
            vdata[iStep * (iAlpha*6)+0] = (float)(radius * -Math.sin(crtAlpha));
            vdata[iStep * (iAlpha*6)+1] = crtZ;
            vdata[iStep * (iAlpha*6)+2] = (float)(radius * Math.cos(crtAlpha));
            vdata[iStep * (iAlpha*6)+3] = (float)(radius * -Math.sin(crtAlpha));
            vdata[iStep * (iAlpha*6)+4] = crtZ + zStep;
            vdata[iStep * (iAlpha*6)+5] = (float)(radius * Math.cos(crtAlpha));

            crtAlpha += alphaStep;
        }
        gl.glShadeModel(GL10.GL_SMOOTH);
        gl.glEnableClientState(GL10.GL_VERTEX_ARRAY);
        gl.glVertexPointer(3, GL10.GL_FLOAT, 0, FloatBuffer.wrap(vdata));
        gl.glDrawArrays(GL10.GL_TRIANGLE_STRIP, 0, 2*(slices+1) );
        gl.glDisableClientState(GL10.GL_VERTEX_ARRAY);
        crtZ += zStep;                        
    } 

}
```

Here's where I call the method:

```
@Override
public void onDrawFrame(GL10 gl) {
    // IN MY DRAWING FUNCTION:
    gl.glClear(GL10.GL_COLOR_BUFFER_BIT | GL10.GL_DEPTH_BUFFER_BIT);
    gl.glMatrixMode(GL10.GL_MODELVIEW);
    gl.glColor4f(1.0f,1.0f,1.0f, 1.0f); 
    gl.glPushMatrix();
        Primitives.solidCylinder(gl, 2.0f, 2.0f, 8, 3);
    gl.glPopMatrix();
```

}

When I had the same in C/C++ (though directly with `glVertex*()`-
functions) it worked.

**Edit**: On the emulator it stays all black as without calling `solidCylinder(..)`

*Result*:

[image]

What am I doing wrong?

Thanks and best regards

Tobias

Comment: So when it "doesn't do what you want it to", what "does it do"?

Comment: Oh, right. Forgot to write about that, sry! :D *Edited*

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your problem sounds very similar to the one that happened here: [Android -- OpenGL doesn't display w/ emulator?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6257363/android-opengl-doesnt-display-w-emulator/6314796#6314796)

If I were you I would complete the two tutorials that he did to make sure that you are not missing anything that is required for OpenGL development and to make sure that you emulator is working like it should. Here are the tutorials for your convenience:

- [Tutorial 1 - Is OpenGL working on my Emulator](http://www.droidnova.com/android-3d-game-tutorial-part-i,312.html)
- [Tutorial 2 - Am I drawing objects to my screen correctly](http://www.droidnova.com/android-3d-game-tutorial-part-ii,328.html)

Let me know if that works for you in the comments.

Comment: Thanks, Robert. The device (HTC Desire with Android 2.2) is behaving exactly the same way as the emulator does. And what I posted is basically all that is being called. Will take a look at the other tips and keep you up-to-date.

Comment: Update: Okay it must have been something in my array arithmetics. Still doesn't work, but you may check Revision 3 at http://stackoverflow.com/posts/6325070/revisions