# OpenGL ES 2.0: GL_COMPRESSED_RGBA_S3TC_DXT5_EXT support?

Tags: opengl-es-2.0

I created a DDS import library for my application. At this point i noticed that there seems to be no support for DXT5 textures, is this correct or i'm blind?

Comment: As far as I know (and I don't know much about embedded GL, therefore no answer), OpenGL ES devices generally don't support S3TC compression modes and usually have other texture compression algorithms suited for their needs, like ETC or PVRTC. So I don't think you're blind, but let's wait for an ES expert.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

devices based on NVIDIA Tegra actually **do** support S3TC formats. Excrepted from "[OpenGL ES 2.0 Development for the Tegra Platform](http://search.yahoo.com/r/_ylt=A0oG7ngc.xNP6X0Af0xXNyoA;_ylu=X3oDMTBybnZlZnRlBHNlYwNzcgRwb3MDMQRjb2xvA2FjMgR2dGlkAw--/SIG=12vq9uedc/EXP=1326738332/%2a%2ahttp://developer.download.nvidia.com/tegra/docs/tegra_gles2_development.pdf)":

```
GL_OES_compressed_ETC1_RGB8_texture
```

This one is normally present in the extensions string.

```
GL_EXT_texture_compression_dxt1
```

The implementation supports specifying textures with the GL_COMPRESSED_RGB[A]_S3TC_DXT1_EXT formats.  Not exported on Tegra, but supported.

```
GL_EXT_texture_compression_s3tc
```

The implementation supports specifying textures with the GL_COMPRESSED_RGBA_S3TC_DXT[1,3,5]_EXT formats.

This is very nasty since there are extensions supported that are not present in the extensions string. But at least they are supported. As for non-tegra devices, it's hard to tell.

Comment: If you add some more information about other devices then i going to mark your answer as correct.

Comment: You can see extensions for ASUS EEE Pad Trasformer Prime TF201 here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8804458/opengl-extensions-on-tegra-3-devices/9258956#9258956 also, some more devices can be found here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2093594/opengl-extensions-available-on-different-android-devices