# OpenGL Extensions on Tegra 3 devices

Tags: android, opengl-es, embedded, tegra

I wonder what new OpenGL ES extensions are on the new Tegra 3 devices? Anyone care to post their device name, OpenGL version and a list of extensions (Tegra 3 devices only, please)? I think other developers could use that too.

On Android, you can do:

```
String oglVersion = GLES20.glGetString(GLES20.GL_VERSION);
String deviceName = GLES20.glGetString(GLES20.GL_RENDERER);
String extensions = GLES20.glGetString(GLES20.GL_EXTENSIONS);
```

Also, is there any real chance that the value of GL_MAX_VERTEX_TEXTURE_IMAGE_UNITS would be nonzero?

Answer (score 4):

**Asus Eee PAD Transformer Prime TF201**

extensions:

```
GL_NV_platform_binary
GL_OES_rgb8_rgba8
GL_OES_EGL_sync
GL_OES_fbo_render_mipmap
GL_NV_depth_nonlinear
GL_NV_draw_path
GL_NV_texture_npot_2D_mipmap
GL_OES_EGL_image
GL_OES_EGL_image_external
GL_OES_vertex_half_float
GL_OES_mapbuffer
GL_NV_draw_buffers
GL_NV_multiview_draw_buffers
GL_EXT_Cg_shader
GL_EXT_packed_float
GL_OES_texture_half_float
GL_OES_texture_float
GL_EXT_texture_array
GL_OES_compressed_ETC1_RGB8_texture
GL_EXT_texture_compression_latc
GL_NV_texture_compression_latc
GL_EXT_texture_compression_dxt1
GL_EXT_texture_compression_s3tc
GL_NV_texture_compression_s3tc
GL_EXT_texture_filter_anisotropic
GL_NV_get_tex_image
GL_NV_read_buffer
GL_NV_shader_framebuffer_fetch
GL_NV_fbo_color_attachments
GL_EXT_bgra
GL_EXT_texture_format_BGRA8888
GL_EXT_unpack_subimage
GL_NV_pack_subimage
GL_NV_texture_compression_s3tc_update
GL_NV_read_depth
GL_NV_read_stencil
GL_EXT_robustness
GL_OES_standard_derivatives
GL_NV_EGL_stream_consumer_external
GL_NV_coverage_sample
GL_EXT_occlusion_query_boolean
GL_NV_timer_query
```

GL_MAX_VERTEX_TEXTURE_IMAGE_UNITS is 0, as expected :'(

What is interesting, compared to the extensions reported by Glbenchmark, these are missing:

```
GL_NV_robustness
```

(not that interesting, it was replaced by an EXT version), but there are some new extensions:

```
GL_NV_texture_compression_latc
GL_NV_texture_compression_s3tc
GL_NV_pack_subimage
GL_EXT_robustness
GL_OES_standard_derivatives
GL_NV_EGL_stream_consumer_external
GL_EXT_occlusion_query_boolean
GL_NV_timer_query
```

Just grabbed the device from colleague's desk and quickly read the extension string, didn't have a chance to get OpenGL version (should be "OpenGL ES 2.0") and renderer (should be "NVIDIA Tegra 3").

Comment: "GL_MAX_VERTEX_TEXTURE_IMAGE_UNITS is 0, as expected :'("
Sad face indeed :'(

Answer (score 2):

[Glbenchmark](http://glbenchmark.com/phonedetails.jsp?benchmark=glpro21&D=Asus%20Eee%20Pad%20Transformer%20Prime%20TF201&testgroup=gl) has a list of extensions.

[Tegra 2 dev guide](http://developer.download.nvidia.com/tegra/docs/tegra_gles2_development.pdf) mentions that the maximum number of vertex texture units on tegra2 is 0. Tegra3 is AFAIK not a massive redesign GPU-wise, it is simply bolting on 4 extra CUDA cores for fragment processing, so I would say that the number of texture units is the same on tegra3.

Comment: thanks for the Glbenchmark link! but as for the extensions, i think it still makes sense for the people to post their extensions, i believe there may be some slight differences between the devices / firmware versions.

Comment: The Tegra 2/3/4 shader-cores are not CUDA capable.

Comment: @kusma Actually I believe Tegra 4 is supposed to be CUDA capable. Isn't it?

Comment: @theswine: Nope. Tegra K1 is, though.

Comment: @kusma Oh, I see. I thought they were the same. Didn't do too much mobile programming lately, kind of stopped at Tegra 3.