# Android camera filter slow on tegra gpus, but fast on others

Tags: android, filter, camera, tegra

I'm developing an app that does live filtering of the camera preview stream ON THE GPU (OpengGL ES 2.0). It's similar to the famous apps "paper camera" (paid) and "cartoon camera" (free).

It works fine and quite fast on my galaxy s2, even faster on an s3 and ok on older Samsung devices. I've also tested it on a Sony Xperia Arc S and htc desire, as well as on several other devices I don't remember, where it isn't quite as fast as on my s2 but at least above 10 fps.

NOW HERE'S THE PROBLEM:
Yesterday I was able to test it on a HTC One X+ and a Galaxy Tab 10.1 (tegra 3 and tegra 2 respectively). On the one x+ it runs at around 5 fps and on the tablet at about 2 fps.

I also tried the before mentioned similar apps (paper camera and cartoon camera) on the one x+ where they also run considerably slower compared to my galaxy s2, even though they SHOULD run faster because of better hardware.

Is there any known problem of tegra GPUs concerning texture upload speed (I have to create a texture for every video frame) or something else that could reduce speed that much?

PS: Reducing camera preview resolution makes it slightly faster, but its still annoyingly slow.

Comment: Are you using vertex shaders?

Comment: i'm using fragment shaders for the per pixel operations, but of course I use vertex shaders for the computation of my varyings (vertex position and 9 UVs for a 3x3 convolution neighbourhood)

Comment: Then this might explain why it is slow on Tegra GPUs: http://stackoverflow.com/a/8808807/21727

Comment: thanks, but I'm not accessing texture units from the vertex shader, I just compute UV's for the textures, so I don't think that explains it.

Comment: Have you tried the app called "[Live FX Camera Effects](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.eawapps.livefx&hl=en)", which is also similar, I am the author and so if it is faster on your X+, I might be able to help you find the problem.

Comment: sorry man, your app is really cool, but it's got the same problem as ours on the htc one x+

Answer (score 1):

Probably the issue is on the fragment shader itself, I've worked quite a lot with shaders on different GPU's and I've allways have found that not a faster GPU means a faster interpretation of the shader. 
Are you using a lot of branching in you fragment shader ('if' conditions), or calls to other functions within the shader? If so, then you should try to avoid branching, also to inline the  code's function into one, and to test GLSL built in functions which might be buggy on the current gpu drivers implementation, and then write your own replacement.

Comment: I doubt that branching is the reason. Although I know that it doesn't support it (for loops with dynamic count won't compile), there's not much of a difference between shaders that use hsv to rgb and rgb to hsv conversion (which uses extensive branching). Might be slow texture upload or slow previewframe delivery.

Comment: do you have any beta or the app itself already in the market? I have a Nexus 7 which uses a Tegra 3. I will check the speed on it.

Comment: thanks for the offer, but our current version will crash on devices without back-camera... gotta fix that soon

Comment: well, let me know when you publish it, and i will be glad to check it out ))