# Does Every Device Which has Android Froyo 2.2(API 8) Supports OpenGL ES 2.0?

Tags: android, opengl-es

Android 2.2 is upgraded from OpenGL ES 1.0 to 2.0. Does Every device which is using Android Froyo(2.2) Supports OpenGL ES 2.0? or the device itself has to be supported for OpenGL ES 2.0?.

Comment: Offcourse it is a question. I am new to OpenGL so I'd like to know that does Every Froyo device supports OpenGL ES 2.0?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I got the answer of my own question. OpenGL ES is a hardware-acceleration Graphics library so it is not necessary that every device which supports Adroid froyo Supports OpenGL ES 2.0. It entirely depends on OS Software and Hardware.Different devices listed  [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2093594/opengl-extensions-available-on-different-android-devices)   with there extensions which has Android froyo but supports OPenGL ES 1.0

Comment: Extensions which you link to in your answer are different to OpenGL ES. Open GL ES is the open GL standard where as extensions are additions to the standard which may or may not be implemented depending on device. See http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/graphics/opengl.html for more details.

Comment: In fact the link in my comment above has a section entitiled 'Declaring OpenGL Requirements'. This shows you how to limit your applications to only devices that support Open GL ES 2.0, which might help you!

Comment: you are absolutely right Andy  but in my mentioned link some users have posted the extensions along with Android and OpenGL versions.i.e some Android Froyo devices with OpenGL ES 1.0 version Which is exactly the answer of my question.

Comment: Ah, fair so, glad you found your answer! :)